# Random number generation

Tags: algorithm

I need a random number generation algorithm that generates a random number for a specific input. But it will generate the same number every time it gets the same input. If this kind of algorithm available in the internet or i have to build one. If exists and any one knows that please let me know. (c, c++ , java, c# or any pseudo code will help much)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator

Comment: Do you want a sequence of random numbers or a single hash code for an input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually the standard implementation of random number generator depends on seed value. 
You can use standard random with seed value set to some hash function of your input.

C# example:

```
string input = "Foo";
Random rnd = new Random(input.GetHashCode());
int random = rnd.Next();
```

Comment: Thanks. I up voted you. And choose your solution, it is easy enough :)

Comment: In fact if uoy need generate just one random number (not sequence) for each output than you can use GetHashCode() function instead of random.

Comment: Integer implementation of GetHashCode return the same int, so not really random.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to look at the built in Java class [Random.](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Random.html)  The description fits what you want.

Comment: If you want better random numbers at the cost of performance you should use SecureRandom instead.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a hash function like SHA or [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5), this will generate the same output for a given input every time.

An example to generate a hash in java is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415953/generate-md5-hash-in-java).

Answer (score 2):

The [Mersenne Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) algorithm is a good predictable random number generator.  There are implementations in most languages.

Comment: Mersenne Twister is far too complex for this requirement. MT has a high degree of recurrence which means it looks back at multiple samples in the history of outputs. Mersenne Twister 19937 for example (which is the usual MT) has a recurrence of 624, meaning that the state buffer, the number of previous samples saved, is 624 entries.

In this case he just wants to generate a single sample from a single seed, so something far simpler with a recurrence of 1 is more more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

How about..

```
public int getRandonNumber()
{
   // decided by a roll of a dice. Can't get fairer than that!
   return 4;
}
```

Or did you want a random number each time?

:-)

Answer (score 1):

Some code like [this](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread1769.html) should work for you:

```
MIN_VALUE + ((MAX_VALUE - MIN_VALUE +1) * RANDOM_INPUT / (MAX_VALUE + 1))
```

- MIN_VALUE - Lower Bound
- MAX_VALUE - Upper Bound
- RANDOM_INPUT - Input Number

Answer (score 1):

All pseudo-random number generators (which is what most RNGs on computers are) will generate the same sequence of numbers from a starting input, the seed. So you can use whatever RNG is available in your programming language of choice.

Given that you want one sample from a given seed, I'd steer clear of Mersenne Twister and other complex RNGs that have good statistical properties since you don't need it. You could use a simple LCG, or you could use a hash function like MD5. One problem with LCG is that often for a small seed the next value is always in the same region since the modulo doesn't apply, so if your input value is typically small I'd use MD5 for example.