# Bouncy Castle crypto library hashing via SHA256

Tags: blackberry, java-me, bouncycastle, sha256

I want to perform SHA256 hashing in a Blackberry application. Searching, I found the Bouncy Castle project has a crypto library for this, but I can't find any samples to show how to use SHA256 hashing.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103652/hash-string-via-sha-256-in-java

Comment: Not a duplicate because it specifically asks for a Bouncycastle example.

Comment: Why aren't the javadocs for [SHA256Digest](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.6/org/bouncycastle/crypto/digests/SHA256Digest.html) adequate?

Comment: Yea,i got the way to use Bouncy Castle crypto api for SHA256 encoding in J2ME.Use it as below.
private static byte[] getSHA256(String key){
   SHA256Digest digester=new SHA256Digest();
   byte[] retValue=new byte[digester.getDigestSize()];
   digester.update(key.getBytes(), 0, key.length());
   digester.doFinal(retValue, 0);
   return retValue;
     
  }
 ~Ragesh Kumar AK

Answer (score 2):

Just reposting user598312's answer as a response instead of a comment, so people know the solution.

```
private static byte[] getSHA512(String key) {
    SHA512Digest digester = new SHA512Digest();
    byte[] retValue = new byte[digester.getDigestSize()];
    digester.update(key.getBytes(), 0, key.length());
    digester.doFinal(retValue, 0);
    return retValue;
}
```

Comment: `key.length` should be `key.getBytes().length` as java is UTF-16 so the string length may be different from the byte length depending on the input. Some platforms are UTF-8 (i.e. Android) but using the byte[] length will make this code more robust :)

Answer (score 0):

BlackBerry has built-in implementations of nearly everything in the BouncyCastle API.  For SHA256, there is [SHA256Digest](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/crypto/SHA256Digest.html).