# How to create a mysql "sha-256" column?

Tags: java, mysql, encryption, sha256

For a password column, is there a mysql feature to store password hashed with "sha-256"? Or should I hash it from java code (like [How to hash some string with sha256 in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531455/how-to-encode-some-string-with-sha256-in-java?rq=1) ) before I store it in database and then hash the password input every time and compare with the database column value to authenticate?

TIA.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can convert the value to hex and use a char(n) column with the appropriate length - 64 in this case. The conversion can be done in MySQL by using the [`sha2`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/encryption-functions.html#function_sha2) function with `hash_length` set to 256.

But for security reasons you should not store passwords hashed using SHA-256.

Instead use [bcrypt](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/) or [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2).

**Related**

- [How can I hash a password in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860943/suggestions-for-library-to-hash-passwords-in-java)

Comment: @Mark Byers What are the security reasons to not use SHA-256? Can you cite something backing up this statement?

Comment: @Tom: bcrypt and PBKDF2 both use [key stretching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching) which means that the password is still relatively secure even if it is a weak password. SHA-256 has no such feature. There's a good discussion about it for example here: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/52041/is-using-sha-512-for-storing-passwords-tolerable

Comment: @MarkByers Thanks!