# MessageDigest NoSuchAlgorithmException in Java

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, rest

So, I've cruised through several Stackoverflow threads and other websites as well whilst trying to find a solution to this.

I am working on a school assignment that requires the use of an instance of MessageDigest.

I will paste my code below, but I have tried getInstance("SHA-256") and getInstance("SHA-1") and getInstance("MD5") all with the same error.

I have also tried adding the provider parameter with "SUN" but then I get a

> NoSuchProviderException.

My school instructions call for `import java.security.MessageDigest`.

I have tried that as well as `import java.security.*` in case something was missing.

I have tried to get a list of providers but that does not give me anything and it won't even compile.

I have followed the try/catch instructions found at [this site](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/messagedigest-getinstance-method-in-java-with-examples/). Still nothing.

I have no idea where to go next and none of the sites seems to have a solid answer for this.

According to Oracle, the process should cycle through providers until it finds one that supports whichever algorithm you selected, and I have tried all three on their list [source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html).

I know it's probably something super simple that I'm overlooking, but I can't seem to get it straight. Any help would be appreciated. Code below

-Jon

Code:

```
package com.snhu.sslserver;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.Scanner;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}

@RestController
class ServerController{
    
    //create instance of message digest
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
//FIXME:  Add hash function to return the checksum value for the data string that should contain your name.    
    @RequestMapping("/hash")
    public String myHash(){
        String data = "Hello Joe Smith!";
       
        return "<p>data:"+data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MessageDigest NoSuchAlgorithmException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16133881/messagedigest-nosuchalgorithmexception)

Comment: Only explicit constructors can throw, you need to define `public ServerController() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException { this.md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256"); }` and delete the field initializer: `private MessageDigest md;`.

Comment: Thank you @PiotrP.Karwasz, I will try that right now.

Comment: @jon, please check the answer below. It is not thread-safe

Comment: @Horse, Thank you! I just checked that out and am working through your recommendation now. I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Independent Usage Issue

MessageDigest instances are not thread-safe.
There is no thread-safety guarantee in the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html)

Please do not use MessageDigest instance like this (unless your controller is request scoped)

### Assumption

1. Thread pools are used by the server
2. Expectation is to reduce the overhead of MessageDigest object creation

### Possible solution

1. Create `ThreadLocal` instance of `MessageDigest`
2. compute digest using this `ThreadLocal` instance
3. Hopefully future `Fiber`s will honor this way of usage (if not, we have much bigger problem in java ecosystem)

### Suggestion

In situations were threads are dynamically created/destroyed, and still the overhead of creating MessageDigest is considerable:

1. Manage a separate executor service(with threadpool), and manage digest using futures
2. or create new MessageDigest instance per request (to avoid unnecessary ThreadLocal overhead.

Comment: Thank you Horse! I really appreciate the detailed response.

Comment: Glad to have helped