# Require similler java code for php encryption script

Tags: java, php, encryption

I have a PHP encryption function. I need a java counter part for the same. Due to my limited knowledge in PHP I am unable to understand. Some one knows both the language, kindly help.

PHP code:

```
function encrypt($decrypted, $keyvalue) {
    // Build a 256-bit $key which is a SHA256 hash of $keyvalue.
    $key = hash('SHA256', $keyvalue, true);
    // Build $iv and $iv_base64.  We use a block size of 128 bits (AES compliant) and CBC mode.  (Note: ECB mode is inadequate as IV is not used.)
    srand(); $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), MCRYPT_RAND);
    if (strlen($iv_base64 = rtrim(base64_encode($iv), '=')) != 22) return false;
    // Encrypt $decrypted and an MD5 of $decrypted using $key.  MD5 is fine to use here because it's just to verify successful decryption.
    $encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $decrypted . md5($decrypted), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
    // We're done!
    return $iv_base64 . $encrypted;
}
```

Thanks in advance
Aniruddha

Comment: Apparently there are comments for each line of code! So you should be able to code it in java, for example: for first line of comment you could start with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531455/how-to-encode-some-string-with-sha256-in-java

Comment: There are some serious key derivation and MAC weaknesses in this code. I suggest using a tried-and-tested library instead of rolling your own cryptography or copy-pasting code off the internet.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Few things are unknown to me, like **MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128** , **MCRYPT_MODE_CBC**. This is why I asked. I altried to execute PHP script from java using JavaBridge.jar. But that also require PHP to be on the machine. So I am kind of stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it.

```
public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] decrypted, byte[] keyvalue) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException{
    MessageDigest sha256 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    byte[] key = sha256.digest(keyvalue);

    MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    byte[] checksum = md5.digest(decrypted);

    //The length of the value to encrypt must be a multiple of 16.
    byte[] decryptedAndChecksum = new byte[(decrypted.length + md5.getDigestLength() + 15) / 16 * 16];
    System.arraycopy(decrypted, 0, decryptedAndChecksum, 0, decrypted.length);
    System.arraycopy(checksum, 0, decryptedAndChecksum, decrypted.length, checksum.length);
    //The remaining bytes of decryptedAndChecksum stay as 0 (default byte value) because PHP pads with 0's.

    SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();
    byte[] iv = new byte[16];
    rnd.nextBytes(iv);
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES"), ivSpec);
    byte[] encrypted = Base64.encodeBase64(cipher.doFinal(decryptedAndChecksum));

    byte[] ivBase64 = Base64.encodeBase64String(iv).substring(0, 22).getBytes();
    byte[] output = new byte[encrypted.length + ivBase64.length];
    System.arraycopy(ivBase64, 0, output, 0, ivBase64.length);
    System.arraycopy(encrypted, 0, output, ivBase64.length, encrypted.length);
    return output;
}
```

The equivalent of MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 and MCRYPT_MODE_CBC in java is AES/CBC/NoPadding. You also need a utility for Base64 encoding, the above code uses `Base64` from the Apache Codec library.

Also, because the encryption key is 256 bits, you'll need the **Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files**. These can be downloaded from Oracle's website.

Finally, do heed ntoskrnl's warning. This encryption really could be better, don't copy-paste from the PHP manual.

Comment: Just FYI: The policy files only apply to the Oracle JRE – OpenJDK, which is the default on most GNU/Linux systems, does not limit the strength of cryptography.

Comment: Thanks a lot to every one.