# Which java libraries used for Hashing

Tags: java

Below code is in Node.js 
Which library in java I can use for same purpose?

const crypto = require("crypto");
let cryptkey = crypto.createHash('sha256').update('Nixnogen').digest();

Comment: Take a look at `MessageDigest` class (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html)

Comment: What is so difficult to google for "java sha256"?

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531455/how-to-hash-some-string-with-sha256-in-java), you can use:

```java
 MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
 byte[] hash = digest.digest("Nitrogen".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory for hashing.

sample code for hashing is as below :

```
String algorithm = "your algorithm value";//ex:PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512
String salt="randomString";
SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt.getBytes(), 1000,256);
SecretKey key = skf.generateSecret(spec);
byte[] res = key.getEncoded();
String hashedPassword = res.toString();
```