# Which packages I should import to be able to use Crypto and encodeBase64URLSafeString?

Tags: java, algorithm, import, package, encode

I am trying below Java code:

```
          byte[] data = Base64.getEncoder().encode((key + number + ts + role).getBytes("UTF-8"));    
          hash = Crypto.hmacSha256(data, secret.getBytes("UTF-8"));    
          String s = key + "." + number +"."+ ts +"."+ role + "." + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hash);    
          result = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(s.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

But I don't know which package I should import to be able to use Crypto.hmacSha256. And I imported java.util.Base64; but it seems it doesn't have encodeBase64URLSafeString, where is this method?

Comment: You are probably looking for commons-codec library https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#encodeBase64URLSafe(byte[])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for commons-codec library and this method https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#encodeBase64URLSafe(byte[])

Comment: How could I import this? I tried import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64, but I get an error "The import org.apache cannot be resolved"

Comment: You need to add it to your classpath

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you know about Crypto.hmacSha256, is there also a external library for this one?

Comment: looks like you are trying to compute hash using SHA256 ? Java has built in API for that. You can use something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531455/how-to-hash-some-string-with-sha256-in-java

Comment: Great! Thank you!!