# How to correctly generate SHA-256 checksum for a string in scala?

Tags: scala, sha

I need to generate an SHA-256 checksum from a string that will be sent as a *get* param.

If found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531455/how-to-hash-some-string-with-sha256-in-java) to generate the checksum.

Genrating the checksum like so:

```
  val digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");      
  private def getCheckSum() = {
    println(new String(digest.digest(("Some String").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))))        
  }
```

prints checksum similar to this:

```
*║┼¼┬]9AòdJb:#↓o6↓T╞B5C♀¼O~╟╙àÿG
```

The API that we need to send this to says the checksum should look like this:

```
45e00158bc8454049b7208e76670466d49a5dfb2db4196
```

What am I doing wrong?

Please advise.
Thanks.

Comment: She message digest will return raw bytes.  You expected format requires them to be encoded as hex

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**[`java.security.MessageDigest#digest`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html#digest(byte%5B%5D)) gives a byte array.**

```
scala> import java.security.MessageDigest
scala> import java.math.BigInteger

scala> MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256").digest("some string".getBytes("UTF-8"))
res1: Array[Byte] = Array(97, -48, 52, 71, 49, 2, -41, -38, -61, 5, -112, 39, 112, 71, 31, -43, 15, 76, 91, 38, -10, -125, 26, 86, -35, -112, -75, 24, 75, 60, 48, -4)
```

**To create the hex, use `String.format`,**

```
scala> val hash = String.format("%032x", new BigInteger(1, MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256").digest("some string".getBytes("UTF-8"))))
hash: String = 61d034473102d7dac305902770471fd50f4c5b26f6831a56dd90b5184b3c30fc
```

You can verify hash with command line tool in linux, unix

```
$ echo -n "some string" | openssl dgst -sha256
61d034473102d7dac305902770471fd50f4c5b26f6831a56dd90b5184b3c30fc
```

**NOTE:**

In case java returns hash of length lesser than 64 chars you can left pad with `0`. (eg. `39`)

```
def hash64(data: String) = {
  val hash = String.format(
               "%032x", 
               new BigInteger(1, MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256").digest(data.getBytes("UTF-8")))
             )
  val hash64 = hash.reverse.padTo(64, "0").reverse.mkString 
  hash64      
}
```

Comment: Small bug here, string representation is missing leading 0's, for example string `39` will return `b918943df0962bc7a1824c0555a389347b4febdc7cf9d1254406d80ce44e3f9` instead of `0b918943df0962bc7a1824c0555a389347b4febdc7cf9d1254406d80ce44e3f9`

Comment: Seems like you meant to use `"%064x"` instead of `"%032x"`, that should solve the padding so you don't need `padTo`

Answer (score 27):

Equivalent, but a bit more efficient:

```
MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")
  .digest("some string".getBytes("UTF-8"))
  .map("%02x".format(_)).mkString
```

Comment: Hash code generated using your mehtod doesnt seem to be equivalent to what is generated using the method from previous answer: https://imgur.com/a/a3Gfv

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. Fixed now.

Comment: @Regressor that's a `Sting.format` instruction. `x` means hexademical, `02` means two digits, padded with 0 if necessary. So, say, 10 (a in hex) is printed as "0a", and 255 (ff) is "ff"

Answer (score 1):

Can use `DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary`.

Something like:

```
DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(
  MessageDigest
    .getInstance(algorithm)
    .digest("some string").getBytes("UTF-8")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since jdk 17, we can use `java.util.HexFormat`

```scala
import java.security.MessageDigest
import java.util.HexFormat

val bytes = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")
  .digest("any string".getBytes("UTF-8"))

val sha256 =  HexFormat.of().formatHex(bytes)
// 1e57a452a094728c291bc42bf2bc7eb8d9fd8844d1369da2bf728588b46c4e75

val another = HexFormat.ofDelimiter(":").withUpperCase().formatHex(bytes)
// 1E:57:A4:52:A0:94:72:8C:29:1B:C4:2B:F2:BC:7E:B8:D9:FD:88:44:D1:36:9D:A2:BF:72:85:88:B4:6C:4E:75
```