# java, how to generate a good random int

Tags: java, android, random

android app, it needs to generate a random int key for different use cases.
it has a function for the random int, which is fine in most time, but in the case if it is called frequently it may return a same number.

```
    int nextRandomId() {
        return (int) SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    }
```

one of the case when build the notification action buttons, there will be multiple `action button` each will have its own pendingIntent with requestid from nextRandomId().

```
Intent broadcastIntent_one = Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
broadcastIntent_one.putExtra("action", ACTION_ONE);  //ACTION_TWO, ACTION_THREE
broadcastIntent_one.putExtra(EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationId)

// adding action for broadcast
   PendingIntent broadcastPendingIntent_one =
      PendingIntent.getBroadcast(application, nextRandomId(), broadcastIntent_one, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

... ...
 builder.addAction(null, "action one", broadcastPendingIntent_one);
 builder.addAction(null, "action two", broadcastPendingIntent_two);
 builder.addAction(null, "action three", broadcastPendingIntent_three);
```

in case of building three action buttons, the log shows some of the random numbers are same:

```
16:00:55.003  nextRandomId(): 400267105
16:00:55.003  nextRandomId(): 400267106
16:00:55.003  nextRandomId(): 400267106
```

so in the `NotificationReceiver` the last two action buttons are all having the `ACTION_THREE`in the extra.

what is a better way to generate a number not duplicate (no clash, efficient)?

Comment: Are you looking for `java.util.Random`?

Comment: no feel it is good enough for our use case, the same function is also used for other like database key field, etc. would like a better one

Comment: is crypto random is good enough?

Comment: If its appropriate you can just use a GUID to always ensure they are different random numbers. Might be a good time to see if using random numbers is the best solution.

Comment: SystemCLock is not random. I can clearly say what will be the next number in the sequence only by knowing call time ;)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html

Comment: I should say "number or not repeat", not really 'random"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot have duplicates, there is nothing efficient that *any* random number generator can do other than saving all the numbers you've already generated and checking.

You can generate bigger and bigger random numbers to reduce the probability of duplicates -- which is what e.g. `UUID` does, reducing it to extremely unlikely.

Using a `Random` or `SecureRandom` will probably have to be good enough, possibly combined with explicit testing to see if you already have generated a given value.

That said, if all you need is to generate IDs that do not have any duplicates on this JVM, the solution is very easy:

```
static final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
public static int getNewId() { return counter.getAndIncrement(); }
```

Comment: What is the advantage of using "AtomicInteger" to generate IDs and incrementing, rather than just incrementing an "int" each time by, for example, +1?

Comment: Thread safety.  That's it.

Answer (score 1):

does it need to be random, or just be unique?

I would recommend against using `uptimeMillis()` because you risk collisions every time that the system is restarted. Use the actual time instead of the uptime to reduce the chance of a collision.

Alternatively, you could use `java.util.UUID.randomUUID();`. It's theoretically possible to generate a duplicate, but I wouldn't count on it.

Answer (score 0):

For you application, you can consider hashing using SHA256 and then taking the last N elements. If your input is a fix string of numbers then you can expect your output to be computed in constant time as well.

See:
[How to hash some string with sha256 in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531455/how-to-hash-some-string-with-sha256-in-java)

If you're looking to assign random IDs to objects I suggest you use a GUID library. This generates a string rather than a number but you can be certain that no two will be alike.

see: https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-generate-uuid-guid-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

based on @Louis Wasserman's answer, this one works

```
static final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger((int) (System.currentTimeMillis()));
public static int getNewId() { return counter.getAndIncrement(); }
```