# Java Hashing Password Doesn't Match

Tags: java, string, hash

After searching in Google and watching a few posts in StackOverflow ( [Java hashing passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754120/java-hashing-passwords) , [Hashing Password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705429/hashing-password) ). I try not to duplicate questions and looking for the answers by myself, but as you can appreciate, this was not the case.

I'm creating a simple library in Java to hash passwords using SHA256 algorithm.

Everytime I create a hash the password generated is different. This happens with SHA256 and MD5 algorithms.

Why is this happening? I think that passwords generated should be the same. I may be totally wrong and confused about how hashing works.

The hashing method:

CipherString.java

```
    public static String cipherPassword(String pwd, String salt) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException
{
    MessageDigest d = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    d.update(salt.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    byte[] hash = d.digest(pwd.getBytes("UTF-8"));

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i=0; i< hash.length ;i++)
    {
        sb.append(Integer.toString((hash[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
    }

    String pwdCifrada = sb.toString();

    return pwdCifrada;
}
```

EDIT:

Old Main.java (bugged code)

```
String username = txtUsername.getText();
char[] password = txtPassword.getPassword();
String hashedPassword = cipherPassword(password.toString(), username);
```

New Main.java (fixed/solved code)

```
String username = txtUsername.getText();
char[] password = txtPassword.getPassword();
String hashedPassword = cipherPassword(new String(password), username);
```

I have deleted all the models, view and controllers which are unneeded.

Thank you all.

Comment: SHA means "Secure Hash Algorithm". Not "Encryption". this algorithm generates a hash-value from a given value. This process is not (or atleast nearly) impossible to reverse - on purpose. Hash-algorithms **are not** encryption-algorithms and **should not** be used in that way (and can't be used anyways).

Comment: I get `70bc98d434ad88c6e99dc513d6bcb160fd8b8a211fc74af07d7b780d6a7fdf61` when I run your program, repeatedly.

Comment: I can't reproduce either. I get the same hash every time.

Comment: @Paul - Yes, I just edited. I meant one way encryption, or hashing.

Comment: @JesusGonzalez I think Paul is referring to the fact that you are calling the hash value a _password_ and using `pwd` for the variable name of the hash. It's a bit confusing.

Comment: @GriffeyDog - True. I have also reproduce it correctly. I'm so sorry I did not insert the code I'm using at the begining. Forgive me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend using a library to handle this for you.

Consider Apache Commons Codec library:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils;

public class HashTest {
    public static String cipher(String pwd, String salt) {
        return DigestUtils.sha256Hex(pwd+salt);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String p = "password";
        String s = "randomSalt";
        String c = cipher(p, s);
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

This will always print

`a0494b0d7ef89bba60f9703e2c438465cd1241cc440a8fc20f4330639d2c9c2f`

If you are using Maven to manage your dependencies you can check the latest version here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec

Or use the current latest:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was by trying this library that I noticed that when I call toString() from a char[] it will print the memory location, not the actual String itself. The getPassword() method will return a char array but by calling toString() will not print the string, in any case I should have done new String(char[]). It has been several days programming and my mind was not so clear. Thank you again. I will use this library in order to hash the passwords.