# Hash a string in Java/PHP no matter the language

Tags: java, php, hash, sha256

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709117/extra-trailing-zero-or-missing-zero-java-php) for background.

Hashing using algorithms like SHA-256 in Java and PHP produce the same result when the string given is in English, but how can I make the two languages produce the same result when the input is in a language other than English (like Chinese for example)?

### Java

```
public static String encodePassword(String password) {
    try {
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        byte[] hash = digest.digest(password.getBytes("UTF-8")); //I've tried messing around with the encoding
        String result = "";
        for(int i : hash) {
            result += String.format("%02x", 0xff & i);
            }
        return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

### PHP

For PHP I use the `hash` function:

```
hash("sha256", $password);
```

### Output (with input as 国)

#### Java

Encoding set to UTF-8: `d1566afa505af0f03b9156d0a9a518a25c2d4568b095ef4ee2dca7fcbb6c29c9`

Encoding set to iso-8859-1: `8a8de823d5ed3e12746a62ef169bcf372be0ca44f0a1236abc35df05d96928e1`

#### PHP

`e1c8436bc8529d791d58c74fefa160dfd678ca8db8f879b8392a42be84f78db3`

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to generate both and show a case where it doesn't match up?

Comment: Assuming correct implementations, SHA-256 will produce the same hash for the same binary input on all platforms. If you suspect otherwise, make sure the binary representation of the text is the same on all the platforms you're using.

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

```
public static String SHA(String text)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    MessageDigest md;
    md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    byte[] md5 = new byte[64];
    md.update(text.getBytes("iso-8859-1"), 0, text.length());
    md5 = md.digest();
    return convertedToHex(md5);
}
```