# Maintaining Session or State for username in android application

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-widget

In web development we have usually seen we use session or cookies to maintain username, and it remains there unless we destroy it or server removes it, i am making an android application, i have a login and a password, what i want is to just, if i get logged in, it should save my username in something similar to session or cookie, and if i move anywhere among intents or screens, it should not be destroyed and i must be able to access it any where. What's the best approach to implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how permanently persisted you want to store the information. If you need it to be remembered after the app is closed you'll need a persitant store but you should ensure that the password is encrypted.

If it's only for the running life of the app you could hold the information in static properties on a class.

Answer (score 4):

store your username & password or session id in [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) on success

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to store in in SharedPrefences. See this [tutorial](http://androidcodemonkey.blogspot.com/2011/07/store-and-get-object-in-android-shared.html). Also use MD5 or SHA algorithm for encrypting. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846484/md5-or-other-hashing-in-android)