# Get unique integer value from string

Tags: java, string, integer, type-conversion

I have different unique strings in the same format. The string looks like this `axf25!j&809>-11~dc` and I want to get unique integer value from this string. **Each time this value must be the same and depends on the string.** I've tried to convert each char of the string to int and then I sum chars to each other. But in case if I have 2 strings with the same set of symbols, it return integer values which are equal to each other. So it doesn't suit me. How can I generate unique integer value from unique string?

**UPDATE:**

Having considered all given solutions I decided to create function which generate unique integer values. I hope that it excludes collisions.

```
public int getUniqueInteger(String name){
    String plaintext = name;
    int hash = name.hashCode();
    MessageDigest m;
    try {
        m = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        m.reset();
        m.update(plaintext.getBytes());
        byte[] digest = m.digest();
        BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(1,digest);
        String hashtext = bigInt.toString(10);
        // Now we need to zero pad it if you actually want the full 32 chars.
        while(hashtext.length() < 32 ){
          hashtext = "0"+hashtext;
        }
        int temp = 0;
        for(int i =0; i<hashtext.length();i++){
            char c = hashtext.charAt(i);
            temp+=(int)c;
        }
        return hash+temp;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return hash;
}
```

Comment: Why not use `getBytes` to convert each character into its ASCII equivalent? Then just sum those.

Comment: Use `String#hashCode()`?

Comment: hashCode does not guarantee the uniqueness!

Comment: @DevlshOne That does not differentiate "aabc" from "cbaa"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot generate entirely unique `int`s from sufficiently long strings [because there are more 10-character strings than 32-bit integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

As far as non-unique solutions go, you can use the standard `hashCode` function, its implementation in Java is reasonably good. For more complex stuff you may consider computing cryptographic hash ([SHA-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2), [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5), etc.)

Comment: @Nolesh No solution does.

Answer (score 17):

You could just use `String.hashCode()` (e.g. `mystring.hashCode()`) to give you a degree of uniqueness but you must ensure you can handle collisions.

Answer (score 5):

You can't guarantee unique integer values from different strings since there are more possible string representations than integers. You can use some well known/defined hashing algorithm to minimize the chance of a collision. You should look at MD5 or SHA.

The java class [MessageDigest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html) should be of some use.

Comment: It's not clear how to get the integer value, as the function returns an array of bytes

Answer (score 3):

You can try with code:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public static BigInteger stringToBigInteger(String text) {
    BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(text.getBytes());
    return bigInt;
}
```

thanks.

Comment: What is the memory consumption for this compared to a String?

Answer (score 0):

Treat the strings as a base `0x110000` representation of some integer (you can get away with a smaller base if you know the range of characters is limited). Convert to a `BigInteger`.