# how to create a user login using java and mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to verify if the username and the password provided by the client. 
When I tried to execute my code, I got an error message:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= 'enki' and password = 'enki$'' at line 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
```

My code clientLogin() method:

```
public static void clientLogin(String username, String password)
{


    try
    {


        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ikub", "root", "root");
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("select username, password from clieent"
                + "where username = ? and password = ?");
        ps.setString(1, username);
        ps.setString(2, password);
         ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
         if (rs.next())
             System.out.println("done");
         else
             System.out.println("error");

         connection.close();

    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR CANT LOGIN!");
        System.out.println("_____________");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

I think something is wrong with my sql query.

Comment: Give a space before where condition in query.

Comment: Note that your logic implies that you are storing cleartext unencrypted passwords in your user SQL table.  This is really bad practice, and you run the risk of taking a bit hit if anyone from the outside ever reads that table.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen or from the inside...

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yeah you're right but as long as I am new to java I was trying to do in that way just to practice, could you please tell me how could I encrypt the password??

Comment: You may start by reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696432/encryption-of-password-in-java-or-mysql).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check tables name
2. You need to Give a space before where

I mean...

"Select username, password " 
+ "Where username =....."

Or

"Select username, password"
+ " Where username =....."