# Get checksum of a jar file

Tags: java

I implemented this example of jar file which checks it's own checksum:

```
   File currentJavaJarFile = new File(MainApp.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
        String jarFile = currentJavaJarFile.getAbsolutePath();// + "jarChecksumTest-1.0.jar";

        byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(jarFile));

        MessageDigest complete = MessageDigest.getInstance(data);

        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        md.update(complete.toString().getBytes());

        byte byteData[] = md.digest();

        // convert the byte to hex format
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < byteData.length; i++)
        {
            sb.append(Integer.toString((byteData[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        }

        if ("L9ThxnotKPzthJ7hu3bnORuT6xI=".equals(sb.toString()))
        {
            System.out.println("Success!!!");
        }
```

But then I run the file I get this message:

```
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: D:\.....\target\jarChecksumTest-1.0.jar MessageDigest not available
```

How I can solve this issue?

Comment: This is pretty magic; surely when you run this code the first time to determine the checksum, and then hardcode it, the checksum will change?

Comment: What do you think this line `MessageDigest complete = MessageDigest.getInstance(jarFile);` is doing?

Comment: `if ("L9ThxnotKPzthJ7hu3bnORuT6xI=".equals(sb.toString()))` - you will never be able to guess the digest. It will change dramatically after writing new string to this if statement

Comment: @MGorgon How I can fix this?

Comment: You can read digest string from external file, so you don't have to change code after calculating digest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code, it is running fine. You may choose any algorithm whether it is SHA/MD5

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class Checksum 
{
    public static void main(String ar[])
    {
        File currentJavaJarFile = new File(Checksum.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
        String filepath = currentJavaJarFile.getAbsolutePath();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try
        {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");// MD5
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filepath);
            byte[] dataBytes = new byte[1024];
            int nread = 0; 

            while((nread = fis.read(dataBytes)) != -1)  
                 md.update(dataBytes, 0, nread);

            byte[] mdbytes = md.digest();

            for(int i=0; i<mdbytes.length; i++)
            sb.append(Integer.toString((mdbytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100 , 16).substring(1));  
        }
        catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Checksum: "+sb);
    }
}
```

Comment: One more question. Which checksum algoritum will be most suitable in this case? What if my jar file 2 GB in size?

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446080/java-hash-algorithms-fastest-implementations.

Answer (score 2):

[`MessageDigest.getInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html#getInstance%28java.lang.String%29) takes a string parameter that is the *algorithm* you wish to use on that message digest, `SHA-256` for example. Creating a `MessageDigest` with a file path makes no sense - Java will try to treat it as a an algorithm, look for an algorithm with the same name as the path, then throw an exception when it can't find one.

Your update makes things worse - you're now passing a stream rather than a `String`! You're creating the MessageDigest `md` correctly, but the one called `complete` is nonsense.

I think what you're trying to do is get the bytes from the file into a byte array? In which case (since Java 7) you can do:

```
String jarFile = currentJavaJarFile.getAbsolutePath();
byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(jarFile));
```

(If you're not running Java 7 see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858980/file-to-byte-in-java) for a few other ways that can work just as well.) The file's bytes will then be stored in `data` (so you can then call `md.update(data)` and then process the digest as before.

Comment: I updated the code. After I take the jar location I have to load it as stream(I suppose). Bu this algorithm accepts Strings. How I can use it for file?

Comment: I updated the code, but I get error at this line `MessageDigest.getInstance(data);`.

Comment: Read berry answer again.

Comment: @PeterPenzov When you have the data, you *update* the message digest you have already with that data, you don't create a new instance using that data as an argument.