# Computing the MD5 hash of a string in scala

Tags: java, scala

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generate MD5 hash in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415953/generate-md5-hash-in-java)

Hi,

I want to compute the MD5 hash of a string in my scala code. Is there any scala or java library i can use to do this quickly, apart from the regular java.security.MessageDigest way ?

Please Help
Thanks

Comment: Why cant you use java.security.MessageDigest? Just wrap it in a public static function to make less clutter in Scala?

Comment: What is the reason you don't want to use `MessageDigest`?

Comment: `net.liftweb.util.Helpers.md5(str)` – of course it only makes sense when you’re already using liftweb somewhere…

Comment: @Debilski: that function just calls MessageDigest again

Comment: @Goran Jovic Of course it does. Why should it implement that function again?

Comment: @Debilski: I agree, but OP doesn't want that for some reason.

Comment: ```scala
import java.security.MessageDigest

def getMD5Hash(myString: String): String = {
    val msgDigest:MessageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")
    val MD5Hash = msgDigest.digest(myString.getBytes()).map(0xFF & _).map { "%02x".format(_) }.foldLeft("") {_ + _}
    MD5Hash
  }
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You may be reinventing a very tiny wheel here, but just write a function to do what you want: take a string, use MessageDigest, and return whatever (hex string, byte array) you need.

```
import java.security.MessageDigest

def md5(s: String) = {
    MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(s.getBytes)
}

md5("Hello")
```

P.S. I don't write Scala, but this works and it's left as an exercise to the reader to turn it into anything other than an Array[Byte]

Comment: @John: `.getInstance("SHA")`?

Comment: @Debilski the bytes in the digest are nonsense as characters themselves when used to create a string. Someone usually wants to format them as hex digits... I know in Clojure this would  be like `(apply str (map #(format "%02x" %) bytes))`

Comment: @John Cromartie You’re correct. I remember I had to do that once… Was something like `map(0xFF & _).map { "%02x".format(_) }.mkString`

Comment: Btw. You need a `=` after the argument list.

Comment: @Debilksi I don't think the first `map(0xFF & _)` is necessary, simply `.map("%02X".format(_)).mkString`

Comment: Is `.map("%02X".format(_)).mkString` hex md5 format reversible? There is a way to do this `BigInt(hexMd5,16).toByteArray` but I'm not sure if it is 100%

Comment: Here's some gists to create md5 strings in all languages: https://gist.github.com/amscotti/2467512

Comment: I came here looking for this: 

`def md5Hash(text: String) : String = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(text.getBytes()).map(0xFF & _).map { "%02x".format(_) }.foldLeft(""){_ + _}`

Comment: I used the same instance, but did messageDigest.reset() before messageDigest.update(str.getBytes())

Comment: Here is complete extension method, can be used as "testString".hash

`import java.security.MessageDigest

object StringExtensions {

  implicit class RichString(val str: String) extends AnyVal {
    def hash: String = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(str.getBytes).map("%02X".format(_)).mkString + "-" + str
  }

}`

Comment: @AjitChahal why do you need to extend `AnyVal`?

Comment: I found it cleaner to go to hex via a BigInt: `def hex(bytes: Array[Byte]): String = BigInt(1, bytes).toString(16).toUpperCase`