# Checking if code was altered

Tags: java

I want to call a few costly update methods whenever my code changes. I hit ctrl-s in Eclipse, this triggers a file save and a hot code replacement, my program checks to see that the file was saved, spends about 5 seconds crunching numbers, and then updates the screen.

I'm using this thing, which I call a few times per second:

```
public static long lastSourceUpdate=0;
private static boolean wasUpdated() {
    File source = new File("/home/user/workspace/package/AClass.java"); 
    long t = source.lastModified();
    if (t>lastSourceUpdate+2000) { // wait for hcr
        lastSourceUpdate=t;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

There are problems with this approach:

1. Checking the file is unreliable, since compilation and hot code replace can finish a few seconds after the file changes. That's why there's a 2000ms delay above. Though the method returns true, the code I just altered isn't updated - or worse yet, Eclipse updates it halfway through the number-crunching, and the result is hopelessly scrambled.
2. Checking files is a hack in any case, it should check classes. The disk probably doesn't need to get involved.
3. It only checks one class, but I sometimes want to check a whole package, or failing that, any changes to the project at all. When a file changes, the package directory's lastModified is not changed. A recursive scan of the folders/packages would work, but isn't very elegant if the package is huge.
4. Looks ugly.

So, what is the best way to check for when code changes? Perhaps reflection? A serialVersionUID check? It's not like classes themselves have a compilationDate field - or do they? Is there some secret value that Eclipse updates? Is there a file that Eclipse changes with every save?

Thanks for checking this out.

Comment: Are you coding this eclipse functionality? OR using eclipse and want to get rid of this? If the later you can disable build on save and build it your self ( click on build icon ) when the time comes.

Comment: Maybe you can implement this as an Eclipse Builder which fires after all other builds have done their jobs? You'll get a full changeset what changed so you don't have to rely on expensive file checking.

Comment: This isn't an eclipse-specific issue. I want the java program to know when its code has been changed, which can occur via Eclipse debug's hot-code replacement, or other means. @MR can an Eclipse Builder easily interact with my program?

Answer (score 6):

Instead of comparing last modified dates, try comparing [MD5 hashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415953/generate-md5-hash-in-java) of the file.

Comment: This won't work at all. Modification dates are exactly as reliable as MD5 hashes. It would suffer from exactly the same problems - the file would be updated before the hot code replace occurs. It's even worse, because you have to read the whole file to check.