# how to check in java, if contents of an imagefolder has changed

Tags: java, file, directory

I have a folder containing image files.I need to check if any changes have been made to the contents of this folder.For the moment ,I am just checking if the names of files in this folder have changed.

I know,that is not a good way to do it.Someone can cheat by replacing one of the images and renaming it as the replaced file..but I cannot quite figure out how to do it..should I take each file and check its modification time or some such?

Can someone suggest/illustrate an alternative?

thanks

Jim

```
public boolean folderContentsChanged(String folderName,String serializedCacheFileName){
    OldFileContents oldContents = readOldContents(serializedCacheFileName);
    List<String> oldFileNames =  oldContents.getListOfFileNames();
    List<String> newFileNames = createFileNamesListFromFolder(folderName);
    if(newFileNames.equals(oldFileNames)){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }

}

private OldFileContents readOldContents(String oldCacheFileName){
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(oldCacheFileName);
    ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
    OldFileContents oldContents =(OldFileContents) oin.readObject();
    return oldContents;

}
```

update:
As per trashgod's suggestion, tried comparing hashes.. the code is given below,It takes about 55 millis for comparing two images ..

```
public class FileHashCompare {
    public static byte[] createByteArrayFromFile(File f) throws IOException{
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        long length = f.length();
        if (length>Integer.MAX_VALUE){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("file too large to read");
        }
        byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)length];
        int offset = 0;
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while((offset<buffer.length) && ((bytesRead=fis.read(buffer,offset, buffer.length-offset)) >=0)  ){
             offset += bytesRead;
        }
        if (offset < buffer.length) {
            throw new IOException("Could not completely read file "+f.getName());
        }
        fis.close();
        return buffer;
    }
    public static String makeHashOfFile(File f) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException{
        String hashStr = null;
        byte[] bytes = createByteArrayFromFile(f);

        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
        md.reset();
        md.update(bytes);
        byte[] hash = md.digest();
        hashStr = new String(hash);
        return hashStr;
    }

    public static boolean sameFile(File f1,File f2) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException{
        String hash1 =  makeHashOfFile(f1);
        String hash2 =  makeHashOfFile(f2);
        if (hash1.equals(hash2)){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try{
            File f1 = new File("/home/me/Pictures/painting-bob-ross-landscape-painting-1-21.jpg");
            //File f2 = new File("/home/me/Pictures/painting-bob-ross-landscape-painting-1-21 (copy).jpg");
            File f3 = new File("/home/me/Pictures/chainsaw1.jpeg");
            System.out.println("same file="+sameFile(f1,f3));
            long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("time taken="+(t2-t1)+" millis");
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: See also how to [generate an MD5 hash in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415953/generate-md5-hash-in-java).

Comment: never thought of that..still,hashing the file may take too much time since the entire image has to be read..will see how it works for my image collection...(sorry for the late reply.was away from the machine)

Comment: thanks doc,it works faster than I thought it would

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at what [Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/monitor/FileAlterationMonitor.html) has: the `FileAlterationMonitor` might do what you want.

Comment: thanks for the link..I need a utility that compares a serialized object which contains the OldFileContents which the current list of Files..may be I will get something by reading the commons io code..

Comment: Ah. You might want to seriously consider @trashgod`s solution: generate a new file and then just do a checksum of the old file and new file to compare. This will work if you only care to know that there is a difference, but aren't particularly worried about what the difference is.

Comment: I have updated the question with code snippet for hashing..thanks for helping out

Answer (score 1):

Basically that's the correct way for Java6, but you have to change `List<String>` to `List<File>`

But that I thing that you have problem with compare Files as `File`, `Files` and `String` forms too, everything is on this forum.