# How to upload a multiple files from hdfs to single s3 file?

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-s3

I have an hadoop job that outputs many parts to hdfs for example to some folder.

For example:

```
/output/s3/2014-09-10/part...
```

What is the best way, using s3 java api to upload those parts to signle file in s3

For example

```
s3:/jobBucket/output-file-2014-09-10.csv
```

As a possible solution there is an option to merge the parts and write the result to hdfs single file, but this will create a double I/O. 
Using single reducer is not option as well

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [FileUtil#copyMerge](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.html#copyMerge(org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20boolean,%20org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration,%20java.lang.String)) method, it allows you to copy data between two file systems. Also i found [S3DistCp tool](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingEMR_s3distcp.html) that can copy data from HDFS to Amazon S3. You can specify `--groupBy,(.*)` option to merge the files.

Answer (score 1):

Snippet for Spark process

```
void sparkProcess(){
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("name");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf)
    Configuration hadoopConf = sc.hadoopConfiguration();
    hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId", awsAccessKey);
    hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey", awsSecretKey);
    String folderPath = "s3://bucket/output/folder";
    String mergedFilePath = "s3://bucket/output/result.txt";
    BatchFileUtil.copyMerge(hadoopConf, folderPath, mergedFilePath);
}    

public static boolean copyMerge(Configuration hadoopConfig, String srcPath, String dstPath) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(new URI(srcPath), hadoopConfig);
    return FileUtil.copyMerge(hdfs, new Path(srcPath), hdfs, new Path(dstPath), false, hadoopConfig, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the java hdfs api to read the files, then use standard Java streamy type stuff to convert to a `InputStream`, then use

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/PutObjectRequest.html

See also

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11116119/1586965