# com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Data read has a different length than the expected

Tags: java, http, amazon-web-services, http-headers, aws-sdk

I am running into this problem in the course of working on a rest api that accepts PUT calls and then streams that contents of the push into S3 using the AWS S3 Java API.

The error I am getting was this:

> Caused by: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Data read has a different length than the expected: dataLength=365; expectedLength=366; includeSkipped=false; in.getClass()=class org.duracloud.common.stream.ChecksumInputStream; markedSupported=false; marked=0; resetSinceLastMarked=false; markCount=0; resetCount=0

I'm using aws-java-sdk 1.9.1.

The problem has appeared since I upgraded from v.1.7.3

Comment: I have made a minor change.  When mentioning an error, use the ">" character to indent it.  Have a good day

Comment: For any one still looking out for a solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53364574/2373449

Answer (score 1):

While it is not clear to me what exactly in the aws sdk  is causing the problem, I fixed the issue by explicitly setting the content-type http header to something other than "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" which is the default value sent by both curl and jquery.