# uploading file to s3 service provided by IONOS

Tags: amazon-s3, ionos

Trying to find a tool which would help me to upload files/folders to s3 storage provided by IONOS hosting. IONOS do not have a native s3 SDK for uploading. If someone has done it via any other methods please let me know it would be very helpful;

Comment: [From](https://docs.ionos.com/cloud/managed-services/s3-object-storage/s3-tools/awscli/awscli-object-lock#upload-objects-to-a-bucket-with-an-object-lock) IONOS uses aws CLI therefore I think we can use AWS java sdk have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30032988/175554) ?

Comment: @ozkanpakdil yes aws sdk worked and now Ionos has its own client for upload activities.