# How can i generate a long hash of a String?

Tags: java, string, hash, long-integer

I have a java applciation in which I want to generate `long` ids for strings (in order to store those strings in [neo4j](http://neo4j.org/)). In order to avoid data duplication, I would like to generate an id for each string stored in a `long` integer, which should be unique for each string. How can I do that ?

Comment: Couldn't you just get the hash of the Strings and cast them to long before storing in neo?

Comment: You cannot achieve "unique for all strings" - long has 64 bits, a string of length 9 has 72 bits, there got to be some strings which will be hashed to the same long

Comment: You can't get uniqueness, since there are infintitely many strings and only finitely many longs.  Can you describe more specifically what you're looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`long` has 64 bits. A `String` of length 9 has 72 bits. from [pigeon hole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) - you cannot get a unique hashing for 9 chars long strings to a `long`.

If you still want a `long` hash: You can just take two standard [different!] hash functions for `String->int`, `hash1()` and `hash2()` and calculate: `hash(s) = 2^32* hash1(s) + hash2(s)`

Comment: A character in java is UTC-16 thus a `String` of length 9 is 144 bits. Also, using two hash functions make so sense. What you want is simply a hashing algorithm that can operate on data of variable length such as MD5 for instance. For sure there will be collisions, but it will remain close to as minimal as it can be with 64 bits of cardinality.

Answer (score 26):

This code will calculate pretty good hash:

```
String s = "some string";
long hash = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(s.getBytes()).getMostSignificantBits();
```

Comment: What could be the percentage of collision?

Comment: it use md5, I am not sure about the percentage

Comment: Logged in just to upvote this. Maybe not the most correct, but practical

Answer (score 7):

Why don't you have a look a the `hashcode()` function of String, and just adopt it to using long values instead?

Btw. if there was a way to create a unique ID for each String, then you would have found a compression algorithm that would be able to pack every String into 8 bytes (not possible by definition).

Answer (score 2):

A simple 64 bits hash can be implement by combining CRC32 with Adler32.

Example in **Java**:

```java
package com.example;

import java.util.zip.Adler32;
import java.util.zip.CRC32;

public class MySimpleHash {

    /**
     * Calculate a 64 bits hash by combining CRC32 with Adler32.
     * 
     * @param bytes a byte array
     * @return a hash number
     */
    public static long getHash(byte[] bytes) {

        CRC32 crc32 = new CRC32();
        Adler32 adl32 = new Adler32();

        crc32.update(bytes);
        adl32.update(bytes);

        long crc = crc32.getValue();
        long adl = adl32.getValue();

        return (crc << 32) | adl;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string = "This is a test string";
        long hash = getHash(string.getBytes());
        System.out.println("output: " + hash);
    }
}
```

```
output: 7732385261082445741
```

Example in **Python**:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import zlib

def get_hash(bytes):
    return zlib.crc32(bytes) << 32 | zlib.adler32(bytes)

string = "This is a test string"
hash = get_hash(string.encode())
print("output:", hash)
```

```
output: 7732385261082445741
```

This Gist compares some hash methods:
https://gist.github.com/fabiolimace/507eac3d35900050eeb9772e5b1871ba

Answer (score 1):

There are many answers, try the following:

- <s>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415953/generate-md5-hash-in-java</s> EDIT: removed, I've missed the `long` requirement. Mea culpa.
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function

Or, as suggested before, check out the sources.

PS. One more technique is to maintain a dictionary of strings: since you're unlikely to get 2<sup>64</sup> strings any time soon, you can have perfect mapping. Note though that that mapping may as well become a major bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

With a 64-bit (long) hash you can have zero collisions if you hash no more than ten billion strings.
A great 64-bit hash function is mzHash64():

```
public static long mzHash64(byte[] data, int start, int length, long seed) {    
    long hash = 0xD45E69F901E72147L ^ seed;

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        hash = 0x3631754B22FF2D5CL * (i + data[start + i]) ^ (hash << 2) ^ (hash >>> 2);

    return hash;
}

public static long mzHash64(String str) {
    byte[] data = str.getBytes();
    return mzHash64(data, 0, data.length, 0);
}
```

Sources: https://github.com/matteo65/mzHash64