# Transferring a file to HDFS from Apache Zeppelin running on a remote server

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, apache-zeppelin

I have an instance of Apache Zeppelin running on a remote server and I'm using Scala to communicate with it via a Spark interpreter.

I would like to transfer a csv file that is stored on that server's directory to HDFS (Hadoop), which is also on a remote server.

I don't have access to any of the configuration files on the server, I am not able to install anything, and I am only able to make commands within Zeppelin.

I have tried to use the standard

```
sc.textFile("file:///test.csv")
```

statement, but it returns the following error:

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 19.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 19.0 (TID 64, 10.244.79.7): java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/test.csv does not exist

I have been told that the reason why I get this error is because Spark cannot see my Zeppelin file system. I am not sure how to enable something like that.

Any advice would be super helpful.

Comment: I would think if its not in hdfs, it would need to be on all nodes of the cluster.  (hadoop fs -put or similar command).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
sc.textFile("hdfs://DNS:PORT/test.csv")
```

where `DNS` is address of name node of your Hadoop cluster and `PORT` is port on which HDFS is listening, where default value depends on Hadoop distribution. Common value is `8020`. You can check it in `core-site.xml` in parameter `fs.default.name` or `fs.defaultFS` depending on your Hadoop version.

Example request can look like:

```
sc.textFile("hdfs://address:8020/test.csv")
```

Comment: Check your user at master server (with address:8020): hdfs dfs -ls /user/ and copy local file to hdfs:  hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal ./resources.conf /user/hadoop/

Comment: Similar actions for config: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38123764/602018

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to read a local file in zeppelin make sure to put that file in the zeppelin folder(zeppelin installation folder) as zeppelin is not able to access files outside the zeppelin folder.