# getting a negative value on md5

Tags: java, md5

Im trying to get an MD5 with java and I receive a negative value.
Can an MD5 result in a negative value?

This is my code:

```
        MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        byte[] sigBytes = md5.digest((sharedSecret+"api_key"+API_KEY).getBytes());
        api_sig = new BigInteger(sigBytes).toString(16);
```

Thank You.

Comment: @Vache - this is Java, not C#.

Comment: Wow sorry, I shouldn't vote to close when I just woke up.

Answer (score 3):

`new BigInteger(sigBytes)` is interpreting your signature as a signed integer, so yes, it would be possible to get a negative number. If you want Your string to contain the hex representation of your md5 value, have a look at some of the answers here: [How can I generate an MD5 hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415953/generate-md5-hash-in-java)

Comment: Is `toString(16)` a bad way to get hex representation?

Answer (score 1):

As [jbowes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9481044/14731) alluded to, `new BigInteger(sigBytes)` is interpreting the signature as a signed integer (meaning the first bit denotes whether the number is positive or negative). If you want it to interpret the bytes as an unsigned number, you should use `new BigInteger(1, sigBytes)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I use following method to get right MD5 hash String (and it never gave me "negative" value):

```
public static String createMD5Hash(String input) {
    try {
        MessageDigest m = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        byte[] out = m.digest(input.getBytes());
        return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(out));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Note that Base64 is class from apache commons:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
```