# read XML nodes in java

Tags: java, xml-parsing

**this is my XML file**

```
<atm>
```

i want to know how can i verify the account no(acno) and password(and password) that i enter in client.java matches with the acno and password in the atm.xml...

Comment: Just a general comment. Please do not store passwords in plain text. Most users have a limited set of passwords so you become responsible for not only your application's security, but all apps that the users login to. Store it as a hash, and convert the password entered by the user to an hash using the same method and compare them instead. Plain text has no advantage in this context except to save a few lines of (simple) code. Example of this is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415953/generate-md5-hash-in-java

Comment: ATM question, worth helping :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your int acno and int password is storing value of client supplied data.And document doc is having the values from xml.Just call a method say verify(acno,password,doc[acno,password]) and traverse it through doc[acno,password] to find a match.