# MD5 or SHA-1 in pseudocode or java without libraries

Tags: java, md5, pseudocode, sha

I am looking for precise algorithm of MD5 or SHA-1. Everything what i found in google, wiki etc. is very confusing, not clear and not precise to me. Does anybody have implementation of that algorithm. I was looking for this in google for several hours yesterday and could find nothing. I know how to generate it using libraries(and I've done it many times).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate MD5 hash in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415953/generate-md5-hash-in-java)

Comment: I've said that i know how to use libraries to generate MD. Please read the description.

Comment: Would it kill you to look at the source code for the class?  It ships with the JDK.  Please use your head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple googling:
[SHA-1](http://home.arcor.de/andi.warnke/SourceCodes/Java/RETE-DB_06/utils/SHA1.java.F_0000.html) and
[MD5](http://enggedu.com/source_code/java/MD5_algorithm_implementation.php)

Comment: Both never worked. First does not use Java notation  for (i=0; i< 2) {
    s = "0"+s;
   }
   if (s.length() > 2) {
    s = s.substring(s.length()-2);
   }
   sb.append(s);
  }   b = MD5STEP(F4, b, c, d, a, inint[13] + 0x4e0811a1, 21); F4 is not declared and it lacks few methods which are called in code.

Comment: Second one SHA1    Convert.intToHex( H1, result); has sth like that which have not even right to work. Don't know why it is published.

Comment: Even if i comment this ConvertintToHex there is always arrayoutofboundsException

Comment: I admit- haven't tried none of this. but sounds like with a little work on this code you can complete your homework.

Comment: I have holidays ; ) I am doing it for someone else. I am going to work on it.