# Set up permissions/features in desktop application?

Tags: java, permissions, desktop-application, modularity

i have a desktop application that consists of 10 features, and some clients asks only for 8 features or 7 features.
i want to have a way to manage adding/removing the permissions/features for the client (only i can control that). so that i can hide/show feature based on a flag.

is that should be done through a property file that contains the name of the feature with boolean flag, or what ?

please give me some ideas, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your other answers, it sounds to me like the following additional details have cropped up; please let me know if I have these wrong:

1. You're delivering your application as a .jar file,
2. Each customer gets their build directly from you, and there's a small number of customers,
3. You configure a build specifically for each customer, and
4. You don't want your customers to be able to modify their feature access.

In that scenario, I'd store the "active" feature list in a hashed property value stored in a .properties file bound into the .jar.  I'll describe one way to do that below.  You generate the properties file just before delivery, add the file to the jar:

```
jar -uf applicationJarFile.jar configuration.properties
```

then sign the .jar and deliver it.  At runtime, your app can load the properties file, run the hash of each feature, compare with the properties you've stored, and determine which ones are off or on.

Your properties, which determine which features are enabled, might consist of a list like this:

```
feature1=enabled
feature2=disabled
feature3=disabled
feature4=enabled
```

Write yourself a utility which hashes the whole string "feature1=enabled" plus a salt value, e.g. "feature1=enabledaKn087*h5^jbAS5yt". (There's code for this built into java; see [How can I generate an MD5 hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415953/generate-md5-hash-in-java), for example.) The result will be an opaque 16-byte number, which you can then store in another properties file to be included in your app: feature1=1865834.... The salt value should be broken into multiple shorter strings in your code so your customer can't just retrieve it and easily duplicate the process themselves.

In your app, at startup, you construct the string above using both the "enabled" and the "disabled" value, run the MD5 of both, and compare it with the stored hash.  That'll tell you what features to enable.

I think a separate .jar or .properties is a bad idea; it clutters your delivery.

You can automate the whole process fairly easily, since you can generate the properties on the fly any time, and bind them into your app.

You can add other "baked in" properties which gives you a lot of flexibility in the final deliverable, including things like skinning for customer branding.

As others have pointed out, though: there's lots of ways to approach this, depending on the rest of the details of your product and your overall goals.  This is one way to do it, given the assumptions above. AFAIK, there's no "canonical" way to do this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using a License management api to do the same, which will give u both security and capability to change License pre/post installations.

It is not advisable to build adhoc licensing capabilty, take a look at [License3j](http://projects.verhas.com/com.verhas.licensor/license3j/license3j/) and [TrueLicense](http://truelicense.java.net), they are both free and can help you gain perspective or better fulfil your requirement

Answer (score 1):

You could try and encode that in a file. I assume each user has an own installation/version of the application, right? I further assume the application should not need to check some web resource. Thus you need to implement that in a file.

However, you should encrypt that file and put the salt and key somewhere in the code where they can't easily be decompiled. Additionally create a hash to check for modifications of the file. That hash could be based on the application's size or something else.

Please note that there's no 100% security and any hacker could still crack your application. But in that case this would need some form of criminal energy not commonly present in the business world.

Comment: so you are with the idea of a property file, but should i manage this file manually from the IDE before generating the final jar ? or there's a better way for doing that ?

Comment: Well, you could either manage the file in the IDE but in that case you could simply not deliver the features they shouldn't get. Alternatively provide all the features but enable/disable them using the encrypted file. What you need to think about then is how to secure that file and depending on your customer base you might want to put more or less effort into that (business customers normally tend to not crack applications :) ).

Comment: i don't understand this part "Alternatively provide all the features but enable/disable them using the encrypted file"  do you mean the file should be outside the jar ? and how to change in the encrypted file ? can you please clarify a little ?

Answer (score 1):

Modularize the application and deploy to each client only those parts that he wants/has access to. There's many ways to do it (the most complete but heavyweight being OSGi), but the specifics depend on your circumstances and requirements.

The quickest way to implement it might be to simply extract your extra functionality in separate JARs, and on deployment update the classpath appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the kind of application,kind of security you want and the number of people likely to use the application.

If the number of clients is not that big you can store their preference in some in memory data structure like a Map . Otherwise you can use file system or a DB depending upon the kind of security you want.

Comment: the client should be able to update the preferences right?so give the default preferences as part of installation and add code in your application which takes in the client preference and update them when necessary.

Comment: the client shouldn't be able to change this permissions because it's about the features available for the client in this application.

Comment: in that case what i understood is that there are only fixed number of clients

Answer (score 0):

This is very open ended - it really depends on what you're trying to achieve, and what you mean by a feature.

One approach is to use a plugin based architecture. e.g. you have an interface

```
public interface Feature {}
```

and provide each of your ten features as implementors of this interface. Then have some method which runs at application start which looks for `Feature` subclasses on the classpath.

You can control which features a client has by including only the relevant features on the classpath, e.g. using maven.

Comment: If features are massive then look at a true plugin framework like OSGi.

Comment: And if features overlap and don't separate very easily, you will have to rethink your ability to make this modular and roll your own more customised solution.