# Can't find unmanaged DLL for adding digital signature to PDF

Tags: pdf, dll, unmanaged, digital-signature

I have trouble finding a library capable for digital signing PDF.

I was able to create [.Net app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378247/digitally-sign-pdf-files) for signing but now I need dll that will work without .Net framework.

Does anyone knows good lightweight library for that? Commercial/NonCommercial

Comment: What platform do you need it for? For Windows you can use our SecureBlackbox (VCL, ActiveX or Library edition would work), PDFBlackbox package.

Comment: Windows is platform. SecureBlackbox is too large :( almost 10MB [libsbb.dll](http://eldos.com/files/sbbx/secbboxlib_win.zip)

Comment: unfortunately, yes, at the moment everything is packed into single DLL which is quite large. Also there was my mistake - PDFBlackbox is not available as ActiveX. If you know pascal, VCL edition is a good option.

Comment: What about iTextSharp (1.286K)? See http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures for the documentation. Download the C# examples here: http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/tutorial/signatures/

Comment: @BrunoLowagie That is a .Net dll, I am looking for non .net library.

Comment: Aha, I'm a Java developer; I'm not familiar with the difference between .net and other DLLs. Sorry.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie and how do you develop iTextSharp then, without knowing Windows?

Comment: iTextSharp is ported from iText. Its development is funded with the revenue made with iText.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it classifies as "lightweight", but you could try with [Amyuni PDF Creator ActiveX](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfcreatoractivex/features/) (commercial). You can use it from C++, Delphi, VB etc. The current version (4.5) takes about 4.7Mb.

Take a look at the documentation for the method [DigitalSignature](http://www.amyuni.com/WebHelp/Amyuni_PDF_Creator_for_ACTIVE_X/Using_the_PDF_Creator_Control/Methods/Document_Handling/DigitalSignature_Method.htm) for more details.

Sample code in VB from the documentation:

```
Private Sub cmdSingDocument_Click ()    
With PDFCreactiveX1    
.Open( "document.pdf", "" )    
.DigitalSignature("Amyuni Dev Signature", "Testing",    
 "signatureImage.jpg", "Montreal", 1, 100, 100, 400, 200, 1 + 2 + 4 + 8)    
.Save("signed.pdf", "" )    
End With    
End Sub
```

*Usual disclaimer applies*.

Comment: Something completely different: On [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/pdf/5161/integrated-pdf-signatures/18525/the-signed-byte-range#t=201610210600075019686) you claimed "I have seen PDF signatures with the byte-range specified for the page contents only. They worked just fine in Acrobat Reader." There is no way to ask back there, so I do it here in a comment: Can you share a sample file for that? It should not be possible, at least not interoperably in current Reader versions

Comment: @mkl I am no longer working in the pdf field, so I lost access to the files database that had those samples. The interoperability however I cannot garantee it, it may very well not work anymore on most recent readers. This was about 4 years ago, by the time I wrote this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074543/comparing-a-signed-pdf-to-an-unsigned-pdf-using-document-hash/12957758#12957758

Comment: At the bottom of that answer you mention you quote from a PDF Reference concerning an object digest. If the signatures you saw signing a single page only were actually object digest signatures, not byte range digest signatures, that would make sense to me. Object digest signatures did not make it into the ISO specification.