# How to get String from byte array which is generated PBKDF2 password

Tags: java, security, pbkdf2

I use solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27928435/5057736):

```
public static byte[] getEncryptedPassword(String password, byte[] salt,  int iterations,  int derivedKeyLength) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, iterations, derivedKeyLength * 8);
    SecretKeyFactory f = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
    return f.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
}
```

The problem is that when I do:

```
System.out.println(new String(getEncryptedPassword(p,s,i,l)));
```

I get a very strange string, something like `���:`, but I want a normal string which I can save in DB. What is my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to convert binary data like a `byte[]` to a String you usually encode it to Hex or Base64 format. Base64 is smaller than hex, therefore I would recommend you to use this one.

For Base64 you can use `java.util.Base64` since Java 8:

`String base64encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(getEncryptedPassword(p,s,i,l)));`

For `Hex` AFAIR Java does not contain the necessary code. You can use e.g. the [Hex encode](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html) from [Apache common codec](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec) :

`String hexEncoded = Hex.encodeHexString(getEncryptedPassword(p,s,i,l)));`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I use Base64 as you wrote and got normal string. The only problem is that I pass length (l) as 128 but get base64encoded string with length 172. How to explain it?

Comment: Base64 encoded messages are always longer because only printable characters can be used in a String (theerefore you are wasting some bits). With hex encoding the length is even longer: it is twice the input length. If you want to keep the data to a minimum don't encode it and save the `byte[]` as `BLOB` or `VARBINARY` in your database (if one of those types are supported as column type).

Comment: Could you say - my mistake is that PBEKeySpec takes (binary) bytes but not String, and return also bytes but not String. But I tried to make `normal` String with characters from these bytes. Am I right?

Comment: The input to PBEKeySpec is totally irrelevant. It outputs always a byte[] which is exactly what it is designed to do. And yes, you tried to directly interpret a byte[] with binary data as String. This will never work for true binary data.

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed explanation. For hex encoding I found https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html see printHexBinary.

Comment: The xml bind module is not available by default in Java 9 (external module). I assume it will not be included in further Java releases. Therefore using it will cause problems in the future. Better directly use Apache commons codec - IMHO it is the defacto standard at the moment.

Comment: Suggest to do base64 encoding to char[] instead of String.