# How can I download a file only if it has changed?

Tags: java

I am making a program that is a launcher for a private server of a game. If i change the server, i have to change the client, so I want it to download only the changed files, and dont overwrite the old files. I am using dropbox to store the files. How can I do this?

Comment: create entry in database, set status to modified and access file with modified status

Comment: there are like 1000 files, I cant do that

Comment: you can store millions entries in db

Comment: Yes, putting them in manually..

Comment: Could it be easier to generate a text files with the changes on the server, download the file, interpret it and then download the necesary files?

Answer (score 3):

In Java 7 you can get Notifications using [WatchService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)

Using this API you can register to various events

```
ENTRY_CREATE – A directory entry is created.
ENTRY_DELETE – A directory entry is deleted.
ENTRY_MODIFY – A directory entry is modified.
OVERFLOW – Indicates that events might have been lost or discarded. You do not have to register for the OVERFLOW event to receive it.
```

The following code snippet shows how to register a Path instance for all three event types:

```
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.*;

Path dir = ...;
try {
WatchKey key = dir.register(watcher,
                       ENTRY_CREATE,
                       ENTRY_DELETE,
                       ENTRY_MODIFY);
} catch (IOException x) {
 System.err.println(x);
}
```

Using WatchEvent you can then call appropriate notification to your application that file is changed and download it

Comment: AmitD I never knew about the watcher. Really useful class!

Answer (score 1):

Maintain version of file on server side using DB or go for checksum to identify the modified file

Comment: +1 using the file size and modification date can be faster than computing a checksum.

Comment: But these values are less reliable. Modification dates can be effected by touch, installers or other factors outside the developers control

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by taking a look at the [Dropbox SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/sdk)

I'd also make sure that each file on the server has a MD5 (other checksum) associated with it.  You could download these checksums and compare them to the files you have installed on your local machine.  If any of the checksums are different, then you can download the file you need.

Have a look at [How can I generate an MD5 hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415953/generate-md5-hash-in-java) and [How do I generate an MD5 digest for a file](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-generate-an-md5-digest-for-a-file.html)