# Java & MySQL - Create a login authentication

Tags: java, mysql, authentication

I have successfully connected my Java app to MySQL, and then I want the user to input their username and password. Then it would send a query to MySQL and look for a spot with that username, and then compare the password given, with the password in the database.
And for the most part, this works. Let's say the username is "ABC" and the password is "def". If when prompted for username, and typed "ABC def" it is saying it is successful, same with a password of "def a". I believe the problem is the rs.next(), and it is checking only for any text before a space.

Any ideas for solutions?

```
    String databaseUsername = "";
    String databasePassword = "";

    // Check Username and Password
    System.out.print("Enter Username: ");
    String name = sc.next();
    System.out.print("Enter Password: ");
    String password = sc.next();

            // Create SQL Query
    Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
    String SQL = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE users_name='" + name + "' && users_password='" + password+ "'";

    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

            // Check Username and Password
    while (rs.next()) {
        databaseUsername = rs.getString("users_name");
        databasePassword = rs.getString("users_password");
    }

    if (name.equals(databaseUsername) && password.equals(databasePassword)) {
        System.out.println("Successful Login!\n----");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Incorrect Password\n----");
    }
```

Comment: Use `PreparedStatement` to avoid SQL injections. Also, what isn't working?

Comment: 1) Don't store plaintext passwords, hash them. 2) If you get any record, then the username and password match so no further check is needed (you do not need to get the value from the database and match it in java).

Comment: The bigger problem is that if you were to type the Username and Password --> "ABC def" in one line when prompted for the username, it is a successful login. And I want it to be two steps. So "ABC def" would not be a correct username, "ABC" is.

Comment: You probably want `AND` instead of `&&` in the MySQL query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `ResultSet` returns a row, the Username and Password have already been checked by the `SQL` statement. You do not need to check again. Additionally, you should put in place a system where the same Username can not be used more than once. (Make it `Unique` or key on it in the database)

Also, use prepared statements and hashed passwords to avoid injection and other attacks.

Comment: I'm still learning MySQL/Java, Can you suggest a website for information on hashed passwords? Thanks!
And the not double checking makes sense, thanks!

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415953/generate-md5-hash-in-java for using an md5 hash. If you have more questions, shoot me a message.