# please help. anyone knows on how to implement M5check-sum in android

Tags: android, sdk

i need a sample code or brief idea on how to implement M5checksum in android that able's to generate from sample string to hash code.

Answer (score 1):

[How can I generate an MD5 hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415953/generate-md5-hash-in-java)

Read what that question says. Since Android uses Java, it will work just fine.