# Generate Unique Id based on object data

Tags: java, file, hashcode

I am doing a small project where end user enters data into a form (`jsp`). I read the data and save into `User` Object, I need to store the user data into a `file` **not into DB**. Here each user data is stored as a single line of text in `.txt` file.

My requirement is to generate a unique id based on contact number and email, currently I am considering email-id to generate `hashcode` which will be the unique identification number for that user. But I do not want to get `-ve` values as unique id. I am using the following code to generate `hashcode'.

```
 static int hashCode(User u) {
    int hash = 37;
    if (u != null) {
        if (u.email != null && u.email.length() > 0) {

            hash = "1@d&$2u".hashCode() + hash
                    + u.email.toLowerCase().hashCode();
        }
    }

    return hash;

}
```

Am I doing anything wrong here? Is there any other way I can generate unique id for each user object based on email. if two user objects have same `email id`, then the `hashcode` **must be same** for both objects.

Comment: Consider to store with the md5 hash: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415953/generate-md5-hash-in-java to get some uniform names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hashcode is not required to be unique even for different values. You should not use it as unique ID. Use email string directly. Email is unique by definition.

If you need a numeric ID then make ID equal to text file line number.

Comment: But I need a number as unique id based on object data not a string. What could be other possible way?

Comment: What's that requirement based on?

Comment: based on email id @SBI

Comment: isn't there a way I can generate unique Id from email or first name or last name or from `combination of other object data members`? @EvgeniyDorofeev

Comment: not as int or long, you can make an integer but you'll need BigInteger