# Arbitrary string to constant length lower case alphanumeric string

Tags: java, hash

Need a way to hash strings into constant length lowercase alphanumeric (hyphen also accepted) strings.
The total size of different values I'll have is < 50.
Thank you.

Comment: Asker has made no attempt made to solve problem

Answer (score 1):

Get the md5 of your string and it will always be a 32 length alphanumeric string. Here is [a help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415953/generate-md5-hash-in-java). FYI, md5 is a one way hashing. You can not revert back to that hash into your original string anymore.