# MD5 implementation in Java

Tags: java, python, jakarta-ee

I was trying to write a code for a Subtitle finder in Java using SubDB api. Since I don't know python much, I don't understand what they are doing to calculate the hash value for a string. The hash is composed by taking the first and the last 64kb of the video file, putting all together and generating a md5 of the resulting data. name is the filename.

```
def get_hash(name):
        readsize = 64 * 1024
        with open(name, 'rb') as f:
            size = os.path.getsize(name)
            data = f.read(readsize)
            f.seek(-readsize, os.SEEK_END)
            data += f.read(readsize)
        return hashlib.md5(data).hexdigest()
```

Can anyone help me with the implementation of above code in Java?

Comment: [No](http://i1.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/000/232/114/e39.png), unless you write some code and face a specific problem.

Comment: I am not able to understand the code. I think I had mentioned that. Since I am not much familiar with reading a file, I think it was a relevant help needed.

Comment: @thefourtheye that pic scared the life outta me :P

Comment: Well why didn't you just ask someone to explain the code to you?  Or learn a bit of python?  In fact, you can pretty much understand what it is doing with ZERO knowledge of python ... if you can assume that the code is correct.

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone help me with the implementation of above code in Java?

Hints:

1. the code to read the first and last N bytes of a file can easily be implemented using a `FileInputStream`, its `skip(long)` method and calling its `read(byte[], int, int)` method twice.  Use `File.size()` to get the file size.
2. generating an MD5 checksum in Java is covered by numerous questions; e.g. [How can I generate an MD5 hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415953/generate-md5-hash-in-java)