# Java jdbc on md5 and parsing date string to mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I'm writing a program that one can register on a web page in java and the details be stored in a mysql database. Can someone help me on how to write a code that encrypts the passwords using md5 and also how to parse a date string and store this date in the database.

Comment: What code have you got so far? What exactly are you struggling with?

Comment: Do some research first!!!

Comment: Welcome at SO! Please show your efforts, what you've done so far and where you got stuck. By the way the [Function and Operator Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/func-op-summary-ref.html) will be a great help.

Comment: Post full code. For MD5 - refer this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415953/generate-md5-hash-in-java  and for parsing date string refer Javadoc of SimpleDateFormat here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

To get MD5 from a `String` instance use [`MessageDigest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html) class. Assume your password is stored in `passwordString` variable.

```
MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
byte[] passwordMD5Digest = messageDigest.digest(passwordString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

To parse string to date use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class.

```
final String datePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy"; // format is day/month/year
String dateString2Parse = "25/12/2004"; // date to parse

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(datePattern);
Date date = sdf.parse(dateString2Parse);
```

`Date` is [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) class.

---

**UPDATE**

Below, there's your code, updated to implement the way I described:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    System.out.println(crypt("password"));
}

public static String crypt(String str) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    if (str == null || str.length() == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("String to encrypt cannot be null or zero length");
    }
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    byte[] hash = md.digest(str.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    return toHexString(hash);
}

/**
 * Converts a byte array to hex string
 */
public static String toHexString(byte[] block) {
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    char[] hexChars = {
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
        'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};
    int len = block.length;
    int high = 0;
    int low = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        high = ((block[i] & 0xf0) >> 4);
        low = (block[i] & 0x0f);
        buf.append(hexChars[high]);
        buf.append(hexChars[low]);
    }
    return buf.toString();
}
```

Comment: private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public static String crypt(String str){
  if(str==null||str.length()==0){
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("String to encrypt cannot be null or zero length");
  }   
  StringBuffer hexString=new StringBuffer();
  try{
      MessageDigest md=MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
      md.update(str.getBytes());
      byte[] hash=md.digest();
      for(int i=0;i<hash.length;i++){
          if((0xff & hash[i])<0x10){
              hexString.append("0"+Integer.toHexString((0xff & hash[i])));
          }

Comment: debug your code, and you will see that your if condition does not work properly. The code I provided works properly and you get byte[] array of md5 hash.

Comment: @FelixOtienoOdhiambo check the update for my answer.