# how to generate incremental unique number in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to get a unique number, incremental(starting from 0) for every user..Can I generate md5 hash? or is there any alternative?

[How can I generate an MD5 hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415953/how-can-i-generate-an-md5-hash)

I see that md5 hash is not a good option from the comments..

Comment: You start a simple counter from zero and if you have a user that have no number just assign it to them. Then you simply increment your counter and again search for non-numbered users. Is that what you need?

Comment: Actually,counter works for me..thanks..