# Generating a random string from user phone number

Tags: javascript, string, random, one-time-password

I am building one application,in which I want to send unique code or referral code to each user.So I want to generate random strings from user mobile number.Each and every random string should be unique for each mobile number.How should I do that ?
Is there any library for javascript or any good links for that ?

Comment: You can just MD5 encode the phone numbers. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415953/how-can-i-generate-an-md5-hash

Comment: you can write your own logic for that, there is no specific answer for your question.

Comment: So to make it clear: You want to create a unique string from a phone number that 1) is unique amongst all of those strings and 2) will be the same if recreated for the same phone number?

Comment: @devnull69 yes u are right .

Comment: MD5 is not unique, it is just relatively unlikely that you create double MD5 hashes for two different phone numbers. But maybe that's already enough for the use case

Comment: I think MD5 is not the correct solution .... I want more robust way to perform this

Comment: Use encryption... with a once randomly generated key.

Comment: is there any popular hash method in javascript to generate random string from your input string ?

Answer (score 0):

In Node Js there are lots of packages available. You can also just use raw code like.

```
    String.prototype.hashCode = function() {
    var hash = 0, i, chr, len;
    if (this.length === 0) return hash;
    for (i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; i++) {
    chr   = this.charCodeAt(i);
      hash  = ((hash << 5) - hash) + chr;
      hash |= 0; // Convert to 32bit integer
      }
      return hash;
      };
```

This rudimentary hashing function will output a hash.