# Android - IllegalBlockSizeException: last block incomplete in decryption

Tags: java, android, encryption

I am using the service like this

```
String value = "test@example.com"
String encrypedValue = EncrypterService get().encrypt(value.getBytes())
String decryptedValue = EncrypterService get().decrypt(encrypedValue .getBytes())



public final class EncrypterService {

    private static Key keySpec;
    private static Cipher encryptCipher;
    private static Cipher decryptCipher;
    private static String passphrase = "IU1ZaypiTiVYc3AtPXMxNWNMYGUmVUF8YUAtUSMuKVI=";
    private static final String KEY_ALGORIGHT = "HmacSHA256";
    private static final String CIPHER_ALGORITHM = "AES";
    private static final String MD5_ALGORITH = "MD5";
    private static EncrypterService service;

    private EncrypterService(){

    }

    private static synchronized void initialize() {
        if (service == null) {
            service = new EncrypterService();
            service.init();
        }
    }

    public static EncrypterService get() {
        initialize();
        return service;
    }


    public String encrypt (byte[] plaintext){
        //returns byte array encrypted with key
        try {

            byte[] encode = encryptCipher.doFinal(plaintext);
            return new String(encode);
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to decrypt data" + e);
        }
    }

    public  String decrypt (byte[] ciphertext) {
        //returns byte array decrypted with key
        try {
            byte[] decode = decryptCipher.doFinal(ciphertext);
            return new String(decode);
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to decrypt data" + e);
        }
    }

    private static void init(){
       try {
           if (encryptCipher == null && decryptCipher == null) {
               byte[] bytesOfMessage = Base64.decode(passphrase, Base64.NO_WRAP);
               MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance(MD5_ALGORITH);
               byte[] thedigest = md.digest(bytesOfMessage);
               keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(thedigest, KEY_ALGORIGHT);
               encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_ALGORITHM);
               encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec);
               decryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_ALGORITHM);
               decryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec);
           }
       }catch(Exception e){
           throw new RuntimeException("Unable to initialise encryption", e);
       }
    }

}
```

stacktrace

```
java.lang.RuntimeException·Unable to decrypt datajavax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: last block incomplete in decryption
Full TraceRaw
EncrypterService .java:59 EncrypterService .decrypt
```

Comment: The problem is with cipher text on `decrypt` method. can you show some code over which calls it and the value of argument.

Comment: I have mentioned the example above the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Issue#1:

[java.security.MessageDigest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html) will provide an instance of MD5 digest.

For this, you need to import the following

```
import java.security.*;
```

---

### Issue#2:

For `encrypedValue`, you are using `value.getBytes()` and
For `decryptedValue` , you are using `encrypedValue .getBytes()`.

Here is some limitation for using `getBytes()`. It is platform independent.
so you should use `getBytes("UTF-8")` instead of `getBytes()`

```
byte[] bytesOfMessage = yourString.getBytes("UTF-8");

MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance(MD5_ALGORITH);
byte[] thedigest = md.digest(bytesOfMessage);
```

Resource Link: [How can I generate an MD5 hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/415971/2293534)

---

### Issue#3: Encoding and Decoding

Mr. [Andrea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2093341/andrea) suggested like below:

> In Java 8, there is an officially supported API for Base64 encoding
>   and decoding
>
> **Sample code using the "basic" encoding:**
>
> ```
> import java.util.Base64;
>
> byte[] bytes = "Hello, World!".getBytes("UTF-8");
> String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
> byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encoded);
> ```

Resource Link: [Decode Base64 data in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15646871/2293534)

Answer (score 0):

```
return new String(encode);
```

The problem is here. `String` is not a container for binary data. The round trip between `byte[]` and `String` is not guaranteed. You should either just pass around the original `byte[]` or else hex- or base64-encode it.