# MD5 Binary String conversion to Byte Array

Tags: java, hash

I would like to compute a simple program, where it will do a MD5, to hash the binary value that I've input.

I've tried google, all the program stated is hashing string.
That's not I'm looking for. I want to hash binary and the result will give me in hexadecimal form.

Below is the code that I've tried, however,
there's an error over at the return statement `return hash` , it state that  byte[] cannot be converted to string.

can someone help me out with this? your help will greatly be appreciated.
I'm new in programming crytographic algorithm.

```
import java.security.*;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class JavaApplication1 {

    public static String getMD5(byte[] plaintext) throws Exception{

        //init hash algorithm
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

        //compute hash
        byte[] hash = md.digest(plaintext);


        //display hash in hex
        System.out.println(tohex(hash));
        return hash;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        System.out.println(getMD5(0111001101101000011001)); 
    }

    public static String tohex(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuilder hexString = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            String hex = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & bytes[i]);
            if (hex.length() == 1) {
                hexString.append('0');
            }
            hexString.append(hex);
        }

        return hexString.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: As `0111001101101000011001` isn't anything valid in Java, what do you actually want it to be? An integer number encoded in binary? Something else?

Comment: binary > hash > hex

Comment: Yes, but binary WHAT? are the 0's and 1's in your example representing individual bits (meaning that what's given there is a 22 bit number)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I generate an MD5 hash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415953/how-can-i-generate-an-md5-hash)

Comment: @fvu the binary value that I've posted is just an example of the binary value

Comment: @freedev i want to generate from  a binary to hash, not string to hash.

Comment: @moon I added that piece of code just to print something at end of conversion... `getMD5` just return the md5

Comment: You seem to be missing my point: are the 0's and 1's in your example representing individual bits?

Comment: yes, it's representing individual bits

Answer (score 1):

I see a number of problems in your implementation, for example:

- cannot pass to `getMD5` function a byte string in that way.
- `getMD5` returns a `String` but you're trying to return a byte array. If you want **the result as hexadecimal string** you should change the `return hash` into `return tohex(hash);`
- `getMD5` declares `throws Exception` which is wrong and too generic, you should declare `throws NoSuchAlgorithmException`.

I suggest to convert the binary string in a byte array in this way:

```
String b = "0111001101101000011001";
byte[] bval = new BigInteger(b, 2).toByteArray();
System.out.println(getMD5(bval));
```

This is a shorter version:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class JavaApplication1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException  {
      String b = "0111001101101000011001";

      byte[] bval = new BigInteger(b, 2).toByteArray();

      MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
      byte[] hash = md.digest(bval);

      for (byte b1 : hash) {
        System.out.print(String.format("%02X", b1));
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: is there an example? the return hash having error too. sorry, I'm new to such program

Comment: thus, this program is hashing the binary value that I've input and the result in hexadecimal, right?

Comment: @moon just change the return value of `getMD5` function into `return tohex(hash);`

Comment: incompatible type, string cannot be converted to byte.

Comment: what I currently would like to achieve is, given a binary values, I would want to use MD5 to hash it and have a hexadecimal output

Comment: I input binary, why do I need to return byte array of binary?

Comment: @moon your question is not clear. May be this is the opportunity to create a new question on SO? :) BTW could you just remove all the unnecessary comments?

Comment: @moon May I ask if you think that my answer is right? If yes [why don't you mark it as correct](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)?