# How do I generate a MD5 hash for a determinate value (for example:character health) on an android game?

Tags: android, md5

I've been taking a look on an android game's folder called Wolf Online, and I've noticed the developers have chosen MD5 algorithm for the game security(I guess)

Can anyone help me to create a MD5 with "used key"? I've heard that MD5 can be read by machines only with a used key... but how do I know the hash's used key value?
I've generated a MD5 hash with a site and then I tested it on the game, but it didn't work...

Here it is a screenshot of how it looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BStA.jpg

I want to change 15990 to another value, but I don't know how to generate the "encryption_check" nor "used_key"

Comment: Check this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415953/how-can-i-generate-an-md5-hash.

Comment: @Juan thank you, I'm going to take a look later.