# Generate md5 in java throws getInstance error

Tags: java, md5

I took the answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415953/how-can-i-generate-an-md5-hash) question. My code is as follows:

```
import java.security.*;

..

MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
```

When I try to run it I get

```
Error:(11, 53) java: unreported exception java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

Is this an issue with Java 11?

Comment: What is your question? The title talks about throwing a getInstance error, but the error in the text is a compiler error. Its very unlikely that this is java 11 related. You may need to [edit] your question and provide a [mcve] after clarifying it.

Comment: Reading the title, the security freak in me got excited that Java 11 no longer supports MD5. Maybe a Java 13 feature :p