# Java: Type-identification by IDs instead of names?

Tags: java

```
String s = "abc";
Integer i = 123;

System.out.println (s.getClass().getTypeName());
System.out.println (i.getClass().getTypeName());
```

Output is

```
java.lang.String
java.lang.Integer
```

I'd like to have some smaller type-identification (like a unique number). I need to store it and therefore I would prefer in a shorter way.

Comment: Use the hash of the name?

Comment: Do you also need to go from the ID back to the class? That influences the answer, because then one-way functions like hash don't really feel suitable.

Comment: `s.getClass().getSimpleName();` ?

Comment: The .hashCode () does not uniquly identify the type. It does identify the content. So 2 integers with different content would have different hashCode but the same type. Not what I want.

Comment: @chris01 You can also `.hashCode()` on the Class object.

Answer (score 1):

You can hash the string, like [`hashCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) , which is available on any object and it returns an `int`. Basically, the `int` is a simple number which needs less storage space and has higher performance. However, the calculation of a hash needs some time.

I say "like", because you can't actually use that method. The method is not guaranteed to return the same result for different executions of the application, so you **must not** store it in a database.

But there are hash functions that guarantee the same result, e.g. simple ones like MD5. ([How can I generate an MD5 hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415953/how-can-i-generate-an-md5-hash))

However, note that a hash is a one-way conversion. If, for whatever reason (possible an unknown reason at this point in time), you need the type as the name again, there's no way to do that.

Comment: But that would be one-way and render the stored data pretty useless as there would be no way (except brute force) to retrieve the classes from the hashes.

Answer (score 1):

Think the proposed solutions in the comments with getSimpleName (RedCam) and hashCode of the Class (Ricky Mo, kutschkern) are the best for my requirements. Thanks!

```
String s = "abc";
String ss = "abcd";
Integer i = 123;
Integer ii = 1234;

System.out.println (s.getClass().getSimpleName() + "   " + s.getClass().hashCode());
System.out.println (ss.getClass().getSimpleName() + "   " + ss.getClass().hashCode());
System.out.println (i.getClass().getSimpleName() + "   " + i.getClass().hashCode());
System.out.println (ii.getClass().getSimpleName() + "   " + ii.getClass().hashCode());
```

Output

```
String   349885916
String   349885916
Integer   1627674070
Integer   1627674070
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a switch statement to assign a 'tag' you can think of yourself to define them with a shorter 'id':

```
 int id = 0;
 switch(s.getClass().getTypeName()) {
  case "java.lang.String":
   id = 1;
    break;
  case "java.lang.Integer":
    id = 2;
    break;
  default:
    id = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Compress the Strings. The range of characters is not very big, so compression should work pretty well.

GZipInputStream / GZipOutputStream should work well.

There is no numerical ID for classes, just the String. So you have to come up with your own method of assigning IDs.