# Convert Byte Array to Hexa Decimal String

Tags: string, jsp, encode, hex

I have written a simple JSP LOGIN page. I have received password in encrypted format. I am decrypting it. So just for a try i am encrypting a sample string, so it needs to then encode byte array to Hexadecimal string, which i am trying to do in the last statement of my code.

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.security.*" %>
<%@ page import="javax.crypto.*" %>
<%@ page import="javax.crypto.spec.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.lang.*" %>

<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Simple JSP/Oracle Query Example</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<%
   Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");

   Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx:xxxx:xxxx","xxxxxx","xxxxxx");
                        // @//machineName:port:SID,   userid,  password

    Statement st=conn.createStatement();

    ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("Select * from Cxxxxxxx");

    while(rs.next()){
        String name=rs.getString("user_id");
        String p=rs.getString("password");
        out.println(name+":"+p);
        out.println("</br>");


    String algorithm1 = "DES";//magical mystery constant
    String algorithm2 = "DES/CBC/NoPadding";//magical mystery constant
    IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec( new byte [] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 } );//magical mystery constant
    Cipher cipher;
    SecretKey key;
    String k="12345abc";
    key = new SecretKeySpec( k.getBytes("UTF-8"), algorithm1 );
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance( algorithm2 );

    String str="test4abc";

    cipher.init( Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv ); //normally you could leave out the IvParameterSpec argument, but not with Oracle

    byte[] bytes=str.getBytes("UTF-8");

    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal( bytes );

    //Problem is in the statement BELOW --->
    String encoded = new String( Hex.encodeHex( encrypted ) );
    }
%>  
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Error I am receiving is that:

```
[jsp src:line #:48]
cannot resolve symbol symbol : variable Hex location: class _check1 String encoded = new String( Hex.encodeHex( encrypted ) );
```

How should I make this statement run or any other alternative to encode ByteArray to HexaDecimal String

Comment: Wait, why do you say "org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex which is in java.lang."?  The class `Hex` is in package `org.apache.commons.codec.binary`, not in package `java.lang`.

Comment: So how to include that package in JSP??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing a similar issue a while back when I was working with JSP.
The error got solved by downloading

```
org.apache.commons.codec.binary 1.5 binary
```

and placing it in the lib folder. Then accessing that function by:

```
org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.encodeHex( encrypted ))
```

This should resolve your problem.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

If `Hex` is meant to be `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex` then you need to import it as such at the top of your JSP (or alternately you can do `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.encodeHex( encrypted )`).  It is definitely *not* inside of `java.lang.*`.  Whoever told you that was incorrect.

Also, please, please, please do not put Java code inside of JSP files.

Comment: SO how could I then convert byte array to HexaDecimal String, as I need  it for encrypting and decrypting.

Comment: Here's a page with many different options:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332079/in-java-how-do-i-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-string-of-hex-digits-while-keeping-l

Comment: [jsp src:line #:48]
package org.apache.commons.codec.binary does not exist String encoded = new String( org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.encodeHex( encrypted ) ); 

This is the error I am receiving when I change that code, my question is how to include this package?

Comment: I have tried these. but whenever I try to include this Integer.to.... function it gives the same error Some library is missing, dont know which one.

Comment: You need to make sure the commons-codec JAR file is on your webapp's classpath.  The simplest way to do that is to include it in your WAR file's `/lib` folder, assuming that you're building/deploying a WAR file.

Comment: Not deploying a war file, I am using oracle application server. So it compiles it byself, but anyway thanks I'll look forward to this idea