# MD5 hash not creating all characters

Tags: md5

i'm using MD5 hashing to encrypt passwords for a program. But it is not creating all the characters and that to some are unreadable.
Here is an screenshot.
link-http://i46.tinypic.com/2qvf2o2.jpg

Any help is appreciated

Thanks
[image: IMG]

Comment: 'US-CERT now says that MD5 "should be considered cryptographically broken and unsuitable for further use."': http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5 (Just trying to save you some grief down the road.  Easy to switch to something better now, possibly harder to do so later, after falling victim to an attack.)

Comment: Lol, and nobody has yet said "Silly hash, you're **not** encryption!" :-)

Comment: you should try sha algorithms it's more safer tha md5.

Comment: SHA1 is not strong enough nowadays.  SHA2 can be good. He's dealing with passwords, so should be using an algorithm that introduces a "work factor" (blowfish for example).  But giving security advice beyond "more research necessary" in SO comments is probably not going to be an effective means of covering the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you want to convert the array of bytes returned by MD5 to a hexidecimal string for display.  Something like **d131dd02c5e6eec4**.

Here's how you can do that:

[In Java, how do I convert a byte array to a string of hex digits while keeping leading zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332079/in-java-how-do-i-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-string-of-hex-digits-while-keeping-l)

Answer (score 0):

You're interpreting the bytes returned by MD5 as raw character data.
Since MD5 does not return bytes that represent characters, you get meaningless results.

Answer (score 0):

What you're getting back is a binary value. So it's a bunch of raw bytes that may or may not map to valid characters in your default codepage. What you should do is convert the byte[] to hex. You can use something like Apache Commons Codec to encode this. http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html#encodeHex(byte[])