# Displaying byte array contents in Java

Tags: java, dialog

I have the below bytes:

```
byte[] data = {(byte) 0x91,(byte) 0x92,(byte) 0x93,(byte) 0x94,(byte) 0x95,
               (byte) 0x96,(byte) 0x97,(byte) 0x98,(byte) 0x99,
               0x0A,0x0A,0x0A,0x0A,0x0A};
```

I want to make a loop in order to make dialogs with byte contents:

```
(byte) 0x91
(byte) 0x92
(byte) 0x93
```

and so on.

Comment: What is your problem? Writing the loop? Creating the dialogs? Getting the string representation of bytes?

Comment: I am java novice how to get string represantation of byte

Comment: Try String.format <http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object...)>.

Comment: search a bit, there are plenty of other similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332079/in-java-how-do-i-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-string-of-hex-digits-while-keeping-l ;  www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0596.html  ;

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert from byte array to hex string in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/convert-from-byte-array-to-hex-string-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a String representation in loop, here's something you can try:

```
for(int index = 0; index < data.length){
    System.out.println(String.format("%02X", data[index));
}
```