# NullPointerException when getting Image Cache

Tags: android, caching, nullpointerexception

I'm using classes from [Android's BitmapFun sample code](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) and have been running into a problem with certain devices(My app doesn't crash on all the devices I have tested, but on other peoples).

Note: The version of Android which this happens on has been: 2.3.3-2.3.7, 4.0.3-4.0.4, 4.1 and 4.2

In my Google developer console, I getting the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.question/com.question.ui.question}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2077)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.question.util.ImageCache.getDiskCacheDir(ImageCache.java:568)
at com.question.util.ImageCache$ImageCacheParams.<init>(ImageCache.java:488)
at com.question.ui.question.onCreate(question.java:58)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4479)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2041)
... 11 more
```

I have looked into this and have found a [question with the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15869920/caching-bitmaps-without-external-sd-card). I have made some adjustments that are suggested from that answer and same problem still persists.

Code that is causing the problem:

```
public static File getDiskCacheDir(Context context, String uniqueName) {
    // Check if media is mounted or storage is built-in, if so, try and use external cache dir
    // otherwise use internal cache dir
    final String cachePath =
            Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState()) ||
            !isExternalStorageRemovable() ? getExternalCacheDir(context).getPath() :
                            context.getCacheDir().getPath();

    return new File(cachePath + File.separator + uniqueName);
}
```

if anyone would know what the issue is here and could explain, that would be of help!

Comment: I am also getting these same problem.check out these `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24121307/nullpointerexception-at-imagecatche/24156251#24156251`.It may be help you.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this issue and discovered my AVD emulator was not configured correctly. Specifically, the null pointer is due to the lack of storage space defined and assigned to the Virtual Device.

To fix the problem create a new or edit your Android Virtual Device with SD Card storage. In Eclipse: Select the Andoid Virtual Device Manager ICON=> Create New=>... Near the bottom of the page is a section called SD Card:  Enter a value for SD Card size.

Here is [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2788833/859764) that describes how to configure the AVD emulator with the proper storage.

Here is [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24121721/859764) that provides a good technical definition why the NullPointerException is generated.