# Secure user login using java hash and salt

Tags: security, hash, authentication, salt, digest

I have been trying for some time now but can't find an answer.... I am new to this topic so apologize if its a basic question...

How do I store user password securely and let user login?

so first time user signup, I will hash + salt the password and store it to the DB. Now, when user logs in how do I check if the user has entered correct password? 
Decrypting the secure password (from DB) and then comparing it with user entered password doesn't make sense? because if I can decrypt it anyone can... 
securing the password and then comparing the decoded passwords doesn't work as they return different values.
here is my code for user signup:

```
String salt = "random232andString";
byte[] bSalt = base64ToByte(salt);
byte[] pass = null;

// pass should be what will be saved to the DB.
pass = getHash("pppppp", bSalt); //user is instance of User class.

private byte[] getHash(String password, byte[] salt) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,     UnsupportedEncodingException {
MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    digest.reset();
    digest.update(salt);
    byte[] securePassword = digest.digest(password.getBytes("UTF-8"));

    return securePassword;
}

public static byte[] base64ToByte(String data){
       BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
       byte[] decoded = null;
       try {
        decoded =  decoder.decodeBuffer(data);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
       return decoded;
}
```

Every time I pass password "pppppp" and the above salt it returns different secure code, something like [B@2430f369. So how do I match user input password with that in DB? hope it makes sense...
thanks in advance

Comment: You can't call `toString()` on `byte[]`.

Comment: thanks... what do mean? where am I calling toString on byte[]?

Answer (score 1):

> Every time I pass password "pppppp" and the above salt it returns different secure code, something like [B@2430f369

That isn't a secure code, that's how Java renders an object such as a `byte[]` that doesn't have a custom `toString()` method, when you try to print it.

`[B` means 'array of byte' and the `@2430f369` bit is the `hashCode` of the object, which is different for every individual object. So calling the same function twice will give you two different byte arrays, with different `[B` representations, despite the contents of the arrays being the same.

If you want to look at what's inside that byte array, a traditional representation would be to [hex encode it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332079).

> So how do I match user input password with that in DB?

In general you create a random salt for each new password, and you have to store that salt so that when you check the password you can generate the hash from the salt that was originally used instead of a new random one.

However. If you are creating a new account system I would strongly suggest using a strong key derivation function like [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) from an [existing library](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/) instead of custom single-hash method. This is the new baseline for password storage these days.