# How to get SHA-1/MD 5 fingerprint of android app in the logcat?

Tags: android, android-studio, sha1

After making the app, I want the Logcat to print the SHA-1 key of the app in its logs.

Instead of running

`keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`

command.

Regardless the app is in debug/ release mode.

Is this possible to be done in android studio ?

Ofcourse after testing I will remove the logcat line so that others possible can't debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would use SHA256 instead of SHA1. That's what I did [in `SignatureUtils`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-security/blob/master/security/src/main/java/com/commonsware/cwac/security/SignatureUtils.java) in [my CWAC-Security library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-security):

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2014 CommonsWare, LLC

  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may
  not use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain
  a copy of the License at
    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
 */

package com.commonsware.cwac.security;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.content.pm.Signature;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class SignatureUtils {
  public static String getOwnSignatureHash(Context ctxt)
                                                        throws NameNotFoundException,
                                                        NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    return(getSignatureHash(ctxt, ctxt.getPackageName()));
  }

  public static String getSignatureHash(Context ctxt, String packageName)
                                                                         throws NameNotFoundException,
                                                                         NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    MessageDigest md=MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    Signature sig=
        ctxt.getPackageManager()
            .getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES).signatures[0];

    return(toHexStringWithColons(md.digest(sig.toByteArray())));
  }

  // based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/2197650/115145

  public static String toHexStringWithColons(byte[] bytes) {
    char[] hexArray=
        { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B',
            'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };
    char[] hexChars=new char[(bytes.length * 3) - 1];
    int v;

    for (int j=0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
      v=bytes[j] & 0xFF;
      hexChars[j * 3]=hexArray[v / 16];
      hexChars[j * 3 + 1]=hexArray[v % 16];

      if (j < bytes.length - 1) {
        hexChars[j * 3 + 2]=':';
      }
    }

    return new String(hexChars);
  }
}
```

If you really want SHA1, you should be able to change the `MessageDigest.getInstance()` call to suit. And, if colon-delimited pairs of hex digits isn't your desired output format (I chose it to match `keytool`), you can convert the `byte[]` into a printable output in some other fashion if you wish.

Comment: Honoured to get an answer from you @CommonsWare :-)