# SHA Hashing behaving unexpectedly in Java - Code Provided

Tags: java, hash, sha256

Reading in a file and then hashing it using SHA-256 I found a [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-sha-hashing-example/) which showed two separate ways to do it.

When comparing the file that I hashed *(Which was a PDF)* against both methods, they did not match up.  I am following the code properly, not understanding why it isn't matching up.

Here is my result:

```
Hex format: b050692edb134da209adf76347f6c5e49db8734edeaa44876606ec8e5559ab4e
Hex format: b050692edb134da29adf76347f6c5e49db8734edeaa4487666ec8e5559ab4e
```

*It looks like it is lopping off the two zeros in the middle, I just don't understand why*

## Java Code

```or-tag-here
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.security.MessageDigest;

public class SHAHash{
   public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
      MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("myfile");

      byte[] dataBytes = new byte[1024];
      int nread = 0;
      while((nread = fis.read(dataBytes))!= -1){
         md.update(dataBytes, 0, nread);
      };

      byte[] mdbytes = md.digest();

      StringBuffer sb1 = new StringBuffer();
      for(int i = 0; i < mdbytes.length; i++){
        sb1.append(Integer.toString((mdbytes[i] & 0xFF) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
      }
      System.out.println("Hex format: " + sb1.toString());

      StringBuffer sb2 = new StringBuffer();
      for(int i = 0; i < mdbytes.length; i++){
         sb2.append(Integer.toHexString(0xFF & mdbytes[i]));
      }
      System.out.println("Hex format: " + sb2.toString());
   }
}
```

Comment: Please don't use `StringBuffer`, and you're missing the values with leading `0`(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of [`StringBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) you should be using [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) (the methods aren't synchronized and you aren't using multiple threads, it's like the difference between a `Vector` and an `ArrayList`). Also, you need to preserve leading `0`(s). You could correct your second loop with something like [`String.format(String, Object...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-). Putting that together like,

```
StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < mdbytes.length; i++) {
    sb2.append(String.format("%02x", 0xFF & mdbytes[i]));
}
System.out.println("Hex format: " + sb2.toString());
```

Comment: That's what I'm talking about.  Thanks for that explanation that makes sense.  Let me make the changes and I will accept your answer.

Comment: This worked, you were right about the formatting of the hex.  I suppose had I iterated through each hex value the answer would have popped right int front of me.

Comment: @milk You might also want to read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332079/in-java-how-do-i-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-string-of-hex-digits-while-keeping-l/2197650#2197650) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9855338/2970947). **Or** just use [Apache Commons Codec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) [`Hex`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html).

Answer (score 0):

The difference between both is that the first adds `0x100` and then only takes a substring.

That way the `toString` call in the first loop always returns a string with a leading `1` followed by the actual value. That way the zero is preserved.

The second loop produces wrong output because the zero digit gets lost.

Comment: I see, that makes a lot of sense.  I didn't fully understand why he had done that.  Your explanation really clarified that.  Thank you.  

I did what @ElliotFrisch suggested by using the string formatter.  I suppose as an integer being parsed, I'm not sure why I expected the leading zero to remain.